# Selecting/excluding sets of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create views or dataframes from an existing dataframe based on column selections.

For example, I would like to create a dataframe `df2` from a dataframe `df1` that holds all columns from it except two of them. I tried doing the following, but it didn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe with columns A,B,C and D
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# Try to create a second dataframe df2 from df with all columns except 'B' and D
my_cols = set(df.columns)
my_cols.remove('B').remove('D')

# This returns an error ("unhashable type: set")
df2 = df[my_cols]
```

What am I doing wrong? Perhaps more generally, what mechanisms does pandas have to support the picking and **exclusions** of arbitrary sets of columns from a dataframe?

Answer (score 719, accepted):

You can either Drop the columns you do not need OR Select the ones you need

```
# Using DataFrame.drop
df.drop(df.columns[[1, 2]], axis=1, inplace=True)

# drop by Name
df1 = df1.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)

# Select the ones you want
df1 = df[['a','d']]
```

Comment: is there a way of just selecting the `n`'th column? ie: `df1 = my_df[[n]]`  where _n_ is the last column of _n_ number of columns, I'm trying negative indexing `[[-1]]`<- it isn't working :( help!~

Comment: @3kstc you can use `df1.iloc[:, [-1]]` this will select all rows, last column.

Comment: what about using `isin` for columns? No need to drop or loop. See my answer below.

Comment: You can also type `df.drop(columns=['B', 'C'])`

Answer (score 236):

There is a new index method called [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html). It returns the original columns, with the columns passed as argument removed.

Here, the result is used to remove columns `B` and `D` from `df`:

```
df2 = df[df.columns.difference(['B', 'D'])]
```

Note that it's a set-based method, so duplicate column names will cause issues, and the column order may be changed.

---

**Advantage** over `drop`: you don't create a copy of the entire dataframe when you only need the list of columns. For instance, in order to drop duplicates on a subset of columns:

```
# may create a copy of the dataframe
subset = df.drop(['B', 'D'], axis=1).columns

# does not create a copy the dataframe
subset = df.columns.difference(['B', 'D'])

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=subset)
```

Comment: Nice.  Is there an advantage/disadvantage to doing it this way versus `df.drop(['B', 'D'], axis=1)`?

Comment: For me the advantage is code readability. I find the use of `drop` to select columns counter-intuitive.

Comment: `difference()` also seems to reorder columns alphabetically by default

Comment: @slizb good point, based on the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/093aa8231eae92ff6cf7ef9564d62289b458aaff/pandas/core/common.py#L352) it looks like there is actually no guarantee about the order of the index returned, as the method uses sets.

Comment: It seems that the drop method is slightly faster (~515 µs vs ~680 µs), at least in some tests on a 15611 rows x 5 columns dataframe of which I wanted to drop 3 columns, in python 3.6 and pandas 0.20.3.

Comment: Sorting can be prevented by passing `sort=False` to `difference()`.

Comment: index has a drop method too. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop.html

Comment: you can `df.drop(['B','D'], axis=1, inplace=True)` so you don't make a non-needed copy.

Answer (score 164):

**Another option, without dropping or filtering in a loop:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe with columns A,B,C and D
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# include the columns you want
df[df.columns[df.columns.isin(['A', 'B'])]]

# or more simply include columns:
df[['A', 'B']]

# exclude columns you don't want
df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['C','D'])]]

# or even simpler since 0.24
# with the caveat that it reorders columns alphabetically 
df[df.columns.difference(['C', 'D'])]
```

Comment: Nice. Failure of `list(df.columns).remove('C')` was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 90):

You don't really need to convert that into a set:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['B', 'D']]
df2 = df[cols]
```

Comment: I timed this, difference and ```[df.columns[~df.columns.isin['B','D']]```.
This answer was quickest. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Also have a look into the built-in [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) function.

Minimalistic but greedy approach (sufficient for the given df):

```
df.filter(regex="[^BD]")
```

Conservative/lazy approach (exact matches only):

```py
df.filter(regex="^(?!(B|D)$).*$")
```

Conservative and generic:

```py
exclude_cols = ['B','C']
df.filter(regex="^(?!({0})$).*$".format('|'.join(exclude_cols)))
```

Comment: This way allows for method chaining.

Comment: This is nice to select columns, but seems very messy to exclude them!

Answer (score 15):

You have 4 columns A,B,C,D

Here is a better way to select the columns you need for the new dataframe:-

```
df2 = df1[['A','D']]
```

if you wish to use column numbers instead, use:-

```
df2 = df1[[0,3]]
```

Comment: `pandas` treats lists and tuples differently as indexes. so`df[('A', 'B')] != df[["A", "B"]]` - note that `df["A", "B"] == df[("A", "B")]`  Not sure I'm a fan....  though there's a quetion as to whether the utility justifies the craziness.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to convert your `set` to a `list`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
my_cols = set(df.columns)
my_cols.remove('B')
my_cols.remove('D')
my_cols = list(my_cols)
df2 = df[my_cols]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly well. Just wondering, are there any features in Panda that facilitate the specification of columns for this type (or more sophisticated types) of column filtering?

Comment: @user273158 Don't know, I am just starting to learn `Pandas` my self.

Comment: Maybe use [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas.DataFrame.drop)?. `df.drop(my_cols, axis=1)` will produce a view of the DataFrame with the dropped columns. All you need is then to assign it to the new DF: `df2 = df.drop(my_cols, axis=1)`

Comment: Use [drop][1] as in this answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18145399/115237  [1]: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop#pandas.DataFrame.drop

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to create a *copy* of a `DataFrame` excluding a list of columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = df.drop(['B', 'D'], axis=1)
```

But be careful! You mention views in your question, suggesting that if you changed `df`, you'd want `df2` to change too. (Like a view would in a database.)

This method doesn't achieve that:

```
>>> df.loc[0, 'A'] = 999 # Change the first value in df
>>> df.head(1)
     A         B         C         D
0  999 -0.742688 -1.980673 -0.920133
>>> df2.head(1) # df2 is unchanged. It's not a view, it's a copy!
          A         C
0  0.251262 -1.980673
```

Note also that this is also true of @piggybox's method. (Although that method is nice and slick and Pythonic. I'm not doing it down!!)

For more on views vs. copies see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961468/2071807) and [this part of the Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) which that answer refers to.

Answer (score 8):

In a similar vein, when reading a file, one may wish to exclude columns upfront, rather than wastefully reading unwanted data into memory and later discarding them.

As of pandas 0.20.0, [`usecols` now accepts callables](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv).<sup>1</sup>  This update allows more flexible options for reading columns:

```
skipcols = [...]
read_csv(..., usecols=lambda x: x not in skipcols)
```

The latter pattern is essentially the inverse of the traditional `usecols` method - only specified columns are skipped.

---

**Given**

Data in a file

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

filename = "foo.csv"
df.to_csv(filename)
```

**Code**

```
skipcols = ["B", "D"]
df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=lambda x: x not in skipcols, index_col=0)
df1
```

Output

```
          A         C
0  0.062350  0.076924
1 -0.016872  1.091446
2  0.213050  1.646109
3 -1.196928  1.153497
4 -0.628839 -0.856529
...
```

**Details**

A DataFrame was written to a file.  It was then read back as a separate DataFrame, now skipping unwanted columns (`B` and `D`).

Note that for the OP's situation, since data is already created, the better approach is the accepted answer, which drops unwanted columns from an extant object.  However, the technique presented here is most useful when directly reading data from files into a DataFrame.

<sup><sub>A request was raised for a "skipcols" option in [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10882) and was addressed in a later [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15799).</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I needed.