# Pandas: Subindexing dataframes: Copies vs views

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

Say I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
foo = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,5)))
```

and I create another dataframe from a subset of my data:

```
bar = foo.iloc[3:5,1:4]
```

does `bar` hold a copy of those elements from `foo`? Is there any way to create a `view` of that data instead? If so, what would happen if I try to modify data in this view? Does Pandas provide any sort of [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_on_write) mechanism?

Comment: so when I do bar.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] it returns a copy, but when I do bar.loc[:, 'a'] it returns a view?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your answer lies in the pandas docs: [returning-a-view-versus-a-copy](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html?highlight=view#indexing-view-versus-copy).

> Whenever an array of labels or a boolean vector are involved
>   in the indexing operation, **the result will be a copy**.
>   With single label / scalar indexing and slicing,
>   e.g. df.ix[3:6] or df.ix[:, 'A'], **a view will be returned**.

In your example, `bar` is a **view** of slices of `foo`.  If you wanted a **copy**, you could have used the `copy` method.  Modifying `bar` also modifies `foo`.  pandas does not appear to have a copy-on-write mechanism.

See my code example below to illustrate:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: foo = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,5)))
   ...: 

In [2]: pd.__version__
Out[2]: '0.12.0.dev-35312e4'

In [3]: np.__version__
Out[3]: '1.7.1'

In [4]: # DataFrame has copy method
   ...: foo_copy = foo.copy()

In [5]: bar = foo.iloc[3:5,1:4]

In [6]: bar == foo.iloc[3:5,1:4] == foo_copy.iloc[3:5,1:4]
Out[6]: 
      1     2     3
3  True  True  True
4  True  True  True

In [7]: # Changing the view
   ...: bar.ix[3,1] = 5

In [8]: # View and DataFrame still equal
   ...: bar == foo.iloc[3:5,1:4]
Out[8]: 
      1     2     3
3  True  True  True
4  True  True  True

In [9]: # It is now different from a copy of original
   ...: bar == foo_copy.iloc[3:5,1:4]
Out[9]: 
       1     2     3
3  False  True  True
4   True  True  True
```

Comment: so when I do bar.loc[:, ['a', 'b']] it returns a copy, but when I do bar.loc[:, 'a'] it returns a view?

Comment: The bar.loc[:, 'a'] acts like a slice, which returns a view, vs bar.loc[:, ['a', 'b']], which uses list indexing which returns a copy. Note that bar.loc[:, ['a']] would also return a copy.

Comment: how about bar['a']? is it a view or a copy?

Comment: @davidshinn Is the highlighted quote still in the docs you linked? I can't find it!

Comment: It has been revised since the original response (the quote is in version 0.13): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: The top link no longer directs to a page with this information.