# Identify view or copy of another pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, chained-assignment

I wonder how I could identify whether I have a view or a copy of another dataframe. Given a pandas.DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'a': [0,8,15], 'b': [42,11,0] } )
```

as well as a view

```
df1 = df.loc[ 1:2 ]
```

and a copy

```
df2 = df.loc[ 1:2 ].copy()
```

which results in

```
>>> df
    a   b
0   0  42
1   8  11
2  42   0
>>> df1
    a   b
1   8  11
2  42   0
>>> df2
    a   b
1   8  11
2  42   0
```

Assigning values to an existing column results in an warning for df1

```
>>> df1[ 'a' ] = 42
value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  #!/usr/bin/python
```

but not for df2. However, the assignment of the value worked in both cases. How can I figure out whether I have a copy or just a view of another DataFrame?

Note that I can not see any difference in the DataFrames `df1` and `df2` by type

```
>>> type(df1),type(df2)
```

by comparing elementwise equality

```
>>> df1 == df2
      a     b
1  True  True
2  True  True
```

by comparing NDFrame objects

```
>>> df1.equals
```

or even by comparing column ordering

```
>>> from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
>>> assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

Note that using the view `df1` alterates as well the original DataFrame.

Possible dublicate: [Pandas: Subindexing dataframes: Copies vs views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960511)

does not answer how I could check this on `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pandas: Subindexing dataframes: Copies vs views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960511/pandas-subindexing-dataframes-copies-vs-views)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property of the dataframe in advance, with `df.is_copy = True` or `df.is_copy = False`, the latter should avoid the warning.

Comment: DataFrame.is_copy is already either a weakref method (`type(df1.is_copy)` is `weakref`) or None (`type(df2.is_copy) is `NoneType `). I would not like to overwrite this.

Comment: What is DataFrame.is_copy actually doing? It seems that by calling it returns the original DataFrame.

Comment: I used to set it as `False` in order to avoid warnings and operate on the current dataframe and not on a copy.