# Slicing a Pandas dataframe with a period index with an array

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I'm trying to slice a pandas dataframe indexed by a period index with a list of strings with unexpected results.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx = pd.period_range(1991,1993,freq='A')    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3),index=idx)
print df.loc[['1991','1993'],:]
```

results in:

```
KeyError: "None of [['1991', '1993']] are in the [index]"
```

If the the last line is switched to:

```
print df.ix[['1991','1993'],:]
```

The output is

```
Out[128]:
        0   1   2
1991    NaN NaN NaN
1993    NaN NaN NaN
```

If instead of a period index I have

```
idx = [str(year) for year in range(1991,1994)]
print df.loc[['1991','1993'],:]
```

Then the output is as expected:

```
Out[127]:
        0   1   2
1991    0   1   2
1993    6   7   8
```

So my question is: how to slice a pandas dataframe with a period index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas doesn't convert the strings into Periods for you, so you have to be more explicit. You could use:

```
In [38]: df.loc[[pd.Period('1991'), pd.Period('1993')], :]
Out[38]: 
      0  1  2
1991  0  1  2
1993  6  7  8
```

or

```
In [39]: df.loc[map(pd.Period, ['1991', '1993']), :]
Out[39]: 
      0  1  2
1991  0  1  2
1993  6  7  8
```

or

```
In [40]: df.loc[[idx[0],idx[-1]], :]
Out[40]: 
      0  1  2
1991  0  1  2
1993  6  7  8
```

---

By the way, when you pass an arbitrary list of items to `df.loc` Pandas returns a new sub-DataFrame with a *copy* of values from `df`. This is not a slice. To slice you would need to use the slicing notation: `a:b`. For example,

```
In [64]: df.loc[pd.Period('1991'): pd.Period('1993'): 2, :]
Out[64]: 
        0  1  2
1991    0  1  2
1993    6  7  8
```

The distinction is important because in NumPy and Pandas [slices return views while non-slice indexing return copies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961468/190597).

Comment: Do you  have an explanation as to why Pandas converts a string to periods when it is not in a list? `df.loc['1991',:]` works even with a period index.

Comment: Fixing this is [an open issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11278) in the current version of Pandas.