# python variable assignment using time slices

Tags: python, pandas

This is more of a newbie python question. I have a pandas dataframe `tmp_df`, which I slice using 3 datetime inputs as follows to extract different time ranges of data:

```
tmp_daily_df = tmp_df.loc[idx[daily[1]:daily[2]],:]
tmp_weekly_df = tmp_df.loc[idx[weekly[1]: weekly[2]],:]
tmp_monthly_df = tmp_df.loc[idx[monthly[1]: monthly[2]],:]
```

Then I pass the resulting 3 dataframes to a function called `compute_stats()`, which calculates various statistics and performs some manipulations to the input dataframe (i.e. `tmp_daily_df`). One such manipulation is adding several new columns to `tmp_daily_df` etc.

```
final_daily_df = compute_stats(tmp_daily_df, 'M','').reset_index(drop=True)
final_weekly_df = compute_stats(tmp_weekly_df, 'M','').reset_index(drop=True)
final_monthly_df = compute_stats(tmp_monthly_df, 'M','').reset_index(drop=True)
```

My question is since python variable assignment operates more like a linkage than a copy I'm wondering will the 2nd and 3rd calls to compute_stats be corrupted by manipulations to tmp_daily_df, which is a time slice of tmp_df which is referenced by tmp_weekly_df and tmp_monthly_df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing a list creates a copy, in other words :

```
new_list = l[:]
```

is equivalent to :

```
new_list = list(l)
```

DataFrames work a bit differently though. 
Take a look at this post :
[dataframes copies vs views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960511/pandas-subindexing-dataframes-copies-vs-views)

DataFrame.loc will return a view when used with scalar indexing/slicing.

According to this :

> Whenever an array of labels or a boolean vector are involved in the indexing operation, the result will be a copy. With single label / scalar indexing and slicing, e.g. df.ix[3:6] or df.ix[:, 'A'], a view will be returned.

you will get a view unless you use an array of labels or a boolean vector.
Using the copy method would give you the desired result.

Comment: is this the same for slicing a dataframe?