# Setting values on Pandas DataFrame subset (copy) is slow

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10))

dft = df[[True, False] * 5]
# df = dft
dft2 = dft.copy()

new_data = np.random.rand(5, 10)

print(timeit.timeit('dft.loc[:, :] = new_data', setup='from __main__ import dft, new_data', number=100))
print(timeit.timeit('dft2.loc[:, :] = new_data', setup='from __main__ import dft2, new_data', number=100))
```

On my laptop setting values in `dft` (the original subset) is about 160 times slower than setting values in `dft2` (a deep copy of `dft`).

Why is this the case?

**Edit**: Removed speculation about proxy objects.

As c. leather suggests, this is likely because of a different codepath when setting values on a copy (`dft`) vs an original dataframe (`dft2`).

Bonus question: removing the reference to the original DataFrame `df` (by uncommenting the `df = dft` line), cuts the speed factor to roughly 2 on my laptop. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Under the hood, `df[[True, False] * 5]` calls `Dataframe.__getitem__()` which calls `Dataframe._getitem_array()` when the indexer is a list. This in turn calls `Dataframe.take()`, which has a property is_copy. I've found that if I run `df.take([0,2,4,6,8], is_copy=True)`, I get speeds slower than `df.take([0,2,4,6,8], is_copy=False)`, with is_copy=True producing equal runtime to dft in your example, and is_copy=False producing equal runtime to dft2. So, the slowdown arises somewhere down the line because of this is_copy property, perhaps during `Dataframe.__setitem__`.

Comment: What the is_copy property is actually used for, however, is pretty murky, and it will probably take some digging in `__setitem__`. I think your feeling about the returned array being a view/proxy is a good one, and I think it has to do with this property.

Comment: Thanks @c.leather. Wonder what those checks are.

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly a new question on SO. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532302/pandas-peculiar-performance-drop-for-inplace-rename-after-dropna), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960511/pandas-subindexing-dataframes-copies-vs-views) are related posts. [This is the link to the current docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html?highlight=view#indexing-view-versus-copy) that explains it.

The comments from @c.leather are on the right track. The problem is that `dft` is a view, not a copy of the dataframe `df`, as explained in the linked articles. But pandas cannot know whether it really is or not a copy and if the operation is safe or not, and as such there are a lot of checks going on to ensure that it is safe to perform the assignment, and that could be avoided by simply making a copy.

This is a pertinent issue and there is a whole discussion at [Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10954). I've seen a lot of suggestions, the one I like the most is that the docs should encourage the `df[[True,False] * 5].copy()` idiom, one may call it the slice & copy idiom.

I could not find the exact checks, and on the github issue this performance nuance is only mentioned through some tweets a few developers posted noting the behavior. Maybe someone more involved in the pandas development can add some more input.

Comment: The question isn't about view vs. copy, it's about the reason for the speed difference. I think my speculation about proxy objects is misleading (and am striking it out). Thanks for the links to the github page!