# Confused by pandas DataFrame memory_usage and copies

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to work out how to free memory by dropping columns.

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

big_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000,20))
big_df.memory_usage().sum()
```

`> 16000128`

Now there are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34683105/575530) of getting a subset of the columns ***copied*** into a new dataframe. Let's look at the memory usage of a few of them.

```python
small_df = big_df[[0, 1]]
small_df.memory_usage().sum()
```

`> 1600128`

```python
small_df_filtered = big_df.filter([0, 1], axis='columns')
small_df_filtered.memory_usage().sum()
```

`> 1600128`

```python
small_df_copied = big_df[[0, 1]].copy()
small_df_copied.memory_usage().sum()
```

`> 1600128`

```python
small_df_dropped = big_df.drop([0, 1], axis='columns')
small_df_dropped.memory_usage().sum()
```

`> 14400128`

```python
small_df_dropped = big_df.drop([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], axis='columns')
small_df_dropped.memory_usage().sum()
```

`> 1600128`

Adding `deep=True` does not change the results.

Adding `del big_df` after making the copies does not change the results.

So none of these smaller copies occupy less memory than the original dataframe, and even stranger dropping 18 columns keeps the memory the same, but dropping 2 *increases* the memory.

What is going on? Are these really copies? If so why aren't they smaller than the original?

Comment: There is one less digit in the first slice. On copy, the size remains same as the sliced  dataframe.

Comment: Brilliant, at the risk of making me look an idiot you can write that up as an answer @Vishnudev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original DataFrame

```
big_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000,20))
big_df.memory_usage().sum()
```

Memory Usage: `16000128` i.e. `1.6x10^7`

On slice,

```
small_df = big_df[[0, 1]]
small_df.memory_usage().sum()
```

Memory Usage: `1600128` i.e. `1.6x10^6`

There is one less digit in the slice. On copy, the size remains same as the sliced dataframe.

On dropping columns 0 and 1 all other columns remain, hence the memory shoots up

```
small_df_dropped = big_df.drop([0, 1], axis='columns')
small_df_dropped.memory_usage().sum()
```

Memory Usage: `14400128` i.e. `1.4x10^7`

Answer (score 2):

From this other question:

[Memory is not released when taking a small slice of a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170939/memory-is-not-released-when-taking-a-small-slice-of-a-dataframe)

"As @Alex noted, slicing a dataframe only gives you a view to the original frame, but does not delete it; you need to use .copy() for that. However, even when I used .copy(), memory usage grew and grew and grew, albeit at a slower rate.

I suspect that this has to do with how Python, numpy and pandas use memory. A dataframe is not a single object in memory; it contains pointers to other objects (especially, in this particular case, to strings, which is the "flags" column). When the dataframe is freed, and these objects are freed, the reclaimed free memory space can be fragmented. Later, when a huge new dataframe is created, it might not be able to use the fragmented space, and new space might need to be allocated. The details depend on many little things, such as the Python, numpy and pandas versions, and the particulars of each case."