# How to create a view of dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (10m rows, 40 columns, 7GB in memory). I would like to create a view in order to have a shorthand name for a view that is complicated to express, without adding another 2-4 GB to memory usage. In other words, I would rather type:

```
df2
```

Than:

```
df.loc[complicated_condition, some_columns]
```

The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) states that, while using `.loc` ensures that setting values modifies the original dataframe, there is still no guarantee as to whether the object returned by `.loc` is a view or a copy.

I know I could assign the condition and column list to variables (e.g. `df.loc[cond, cols]`), but I'm generally curious to know whether it is possible to create a view of a dataframe.

---

**Edit**: Related questions:

- [What rules does Pandas use to generate a view vs a copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23296282/5276797)
- [Pandas: Subindexing dataframes: Copies vs views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17960511/5276797)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I want to do the same...

Comment: No I haven't! My current understanding is that you cannot control what is a view and what is a copy. You have to trust that memory management (in numpy) is efficient...

Comment: With respect to your first observation on whether the object returned by .loc is a view or copy, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296545/5305519) might answer your question.

Comment: @JattYeo very interesting thanks, I've added a link to the question in my question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You generally can't return a view.

Your answer lies in the pandas docs: 
[returning-a-view-versus-a-copy.](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

> Whenever an array of labels or a boolean vector are involved in the
>   indexing operation, the result will be a copy. With single label /
>   scalar indexing and slicing, e.g. df.ix[3:6] or df.ix[:, 'A'], a view
>   will be returned.

This answer was found in the following post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960511/pandas-subindexing-dataframes-copies-vs-views?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: So, answer to the topicstarter's question is "no, it's not generally possible to create a view of a pandas dataframe if condition is complex enough (ie contains an array of labels)"?

Comment: The top link now redirects to a page without this text (or seemingly any mention of how specifically to return a view vs a copy, only SettingWithCopy warning explanations)

Comment: Edited the answer with @Anatoly Alekseev input and updated link.

Comment: Latest Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) say that it no longer make any guarantee whether it return a view or a copy

Comment: A shame.  `df_view=df_view.apply(...)` is so much clearer than `df.loc[ind1, ind2]=df.loc[ind1, ind2].apply(...)` and much more likely to fit on a single line.