# How can I modify a dataframe element from a Series defined through df.loc[row]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, in-place

I have code where a function/method accepts a Series (row from df) and is supposed to modify it in-place, such that changes are reflected in the original df.  However, I seem unable to *force* the modification as a view rather than a copy.  Information from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486049/force-return-of-view-rather-than-copy-in-pandas) on Stack Overflow do not resolve the issue as given by the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__ # 0.24.2

ROW_NAME = "r1"
COL_NAME = "B"
NEW_VAL = 100.0

# df I would like to modify in-place
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[[1], [2], [3,4]], "B": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]}, index=["r1", "r2", "r3"])

# a row (Series reference) is the input param to a function that should modify df in-place
record = df.loc[ROW_NAME]
record.loc[COL_NAME] = NEW_VAL
assert df.loc[ROW_NAME, COL_NAME] == NEW_VAL #False
```

The line starting with `record.loc` results in the familiar warning:
`SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`, which might make sense, except that `record` appears to reference `df` and can be modified in-place under some circumstances.  An example of this:

```
record = df.loc[ROW_NAME]
record.loc["A"].append(NEW_VALUE)
assert NEW_VALUE in df.loc["r1", "A"] # True
```

My question is: how can I force a modification the float value at `df.loc[ROW_NAME, COL_NAME]` in-place from the Series `record`?  Bonus points for clarifying why it is possible to modify column A in-place but not column B in the examples above.

Other related questions:

- [create a view of a dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972778/how-to-create-a-view-of-dataframe-in-pandas)
- [sub-indexing dataframes:copies vs views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960511/pandas-subindexing-dataframes-copies-vs-views)
- [What rules does Pandas use to generate a view vs a copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sources linked in the question and a thorough reading of the documentation, it does not appear possible to enforce returning a view vs copy of a Series generated from a DataFrame row.

As @Lilith Schneider points out, the original confusion over this comes from the fact that `record = df.loc["r1"]` returns a shallow copy - some hybrid of a copy and view that may cause confusion and lead to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior is confusing because `record` in this case is a shallow copy of your data frame row.

If you refer to [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367442/pandas-dataframe-view-vs-copy-how-do-i-tell) it sounds like `.loc[]` is generally expected to return a copy and not a view, and that assignment will not work if the `.loc`s have been chained.

I did confirm if you modify the original data frame directly it will work.

```
df.loc[ROW_NAME, COL_NAME] = NEW_VAL
assert(df.loc[ROW_NAME, COL_NAME] == NEW_VAL) # True
```

And as for the `.append` still working, this is why I mentioned the "shallow" copy behavior. Your new record copy still contains a reference to the original list in column A. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they) for a refresher on the difference between binding to a new object vs mutating an existing object.

Comment: this is a good start, but I pass the series (`record`) to a function which should modify the df in-place.  Is there a way to force `record` to be a view to the original df row?

Comment: is there a way you can pass the `ROW_NAME` used to created the series into the function so that you can modify the original dataframe? I don't think pandas provides views.

Comment: Looking at other references, I think the shallow copy is critical, as you've pointed out.  At least one other reference suggests it is not possible to force return a view.  It looks like my best option is to change the function signature to take the `df` and `row_name`.