# Slicing a Pandas DataFrame into a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, copy, slice

I would like to slice a DataFrame with a Boolean index obtaining a copy, and then do stuff on that copy independently of the original DataFrame.

Judging from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961468/5429658), selecting with `.loc` using a Boolean array will hand me back a copy, but then, if I try to change the copy, `SettingWithCopyWarning` gets in the way. Would this then be the correct way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
# create a new dataframe from the sliced copy
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d1.loc[d1.a > 1, :])
# do stuff with d2, keep d1 unchanged
```

Comment: `SettingWithCopyWarning` is just a warning. It tells you that modifications you do on that DataFrame will not change the original DataFrame. You can disable them altogether or just use `d2.is_copy = None`  after the assignment.

Comment: DataFrame.is_copy is no longer in the API.

Answer (score 25):

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), new `DataFrame` constructor is not necessary:

```
d2 = d1[d1.a > 1].copy()
```

Explanation of warning:

If you modify values in `d2` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`d1`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: That's what I was using, I changed it because I seem to have read in the docs somewhere that `.copy()` is not the recommended way, but I may have been mistaken.

Comment: Yes, if need new object need copy. if not need original `d1 = d1[d1.a > 1]` should work also.