# How to replace selected rows of pandas dataframe with a np array, sequentially?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
     A  B  C
0  NaN  2  6
1  3.0  4  0
2  NaN  0  4
3  NaN  1  2
```

where I have a column A that has NaN values in some rows (not necessarily consecutive).

I want to replace these values *not* with a constant value (which `pd.fillna` does), but rather with the values from a numpy array.

So the desired outcome is:

```
     A  B  C
0  1.0  2  6
1  3.0  4  0
2  5.0  0  4
3  7.0  1  2
```

I'm not sure the `.replace` method will help here as well, since that seems to replace `value <-> value` via dictionary. Whereas here I want to sequentially change NaN to its corresponding value (by index) in the np array.

I tried:

**MWE:**

```
huh = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, 6],
                    [3, 4, 0],
                    [np.nan, 0, 4],
                    [np.nan, 1, 2]],
                   columns=list('ABC'))

huh.A[huh.A.isnull()] = np.array([1,5,7])  # what i want to do, but this gives error
```

gives the error

> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>   See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>     '''

I read the docs but I can't understand how to do this with `.loc`.
How do I do this properly, preferably without a for loop?

Other info:

- The number of elements in the np array will always match the number of NaN in the dataframe, so your answer does not need to check for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close, need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for avoid [chained assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463589/pandas-chained-assignments/21463854#21463854):

```
huh.loc[huh.A.isnull(), 'A'] = np.array([1,5,7])
print (huh)
     A  B  C
0  1.0  2  6
1  3.0  4  0
2  5.0  0  4
3  7.0  1  2
```

Comment: what happens when there is mismatch in length i.2 `when array has more than 3 values ` or `huh['A'] has more NaN than assigning array`

Comment: Here is is not problem, OP notice `The number of elements in the np array will always match the number of NaN in the dataframe, so your answer does not need to check for this.`

Comment: yes, I get `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,)
` when mismatch in lengths

Comment: @pyd - I think need check lengths, need some time for solution.

Comment: it's so weird, it works with my minmal example, but when I implement it in my actual code, I still get the SettingwithcopyWarning. (using `.loc`) Yet, the `nan` in the main 'huh' dataframe gets replaced regardless.. So, I get my desired result, but the warning still shows.. I'll need some time to debug this.. but thanks for the quick reply nonetheless.

Comment: @QuestionAsker - I think should be also different problem, check if not necesary [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44966873/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael You were right, I needed `.copy()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### `zip`

This should account for uneven lengths

```
m = huh.A.isna()
a = np.array([1, 5, 7])
s = pd.Series(dict(zip(huh.index[m], a)))

huh.fillna({'A': s})

     A  B  C
0  1.0  2  6
1  3.0  4  0
2  5.0  0  4
3  7.0  1  2
```