# WRITE only first N rows from pandas df to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can I write only first N rows or from P to Q rows to csv from pandas dataframe without subseting the df first? I cannot subset the data I want to export because of memory issues.

I am thinking of a function which writes to csv row by row.

Thank you

Comment: just slice the dataframe?

Comment: Can't because of memory issues. I could go over details but I doubt we will find a solution there. I am asking if it is available to the to_csv mehtod although I could not find it in the doc. Or just a function that writes directly row by row to the csv

Comment: Look at the `chunksize` parameter of the `.to_csv()` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: chunksize refers to how many rows are exported at a time... still the whole csv gets exported

Comment: FYI, each of the below seem to work in copying the file contents over, but they also seem to add an additional column seemingly corresponding to the index. Highly suggest removing index when moving dataframe to csv (just add argument so it is`.to_csv(index=False)`)

Answer (score 14):

- Use [head](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html#pandas.DataFrame.head)- Return the first n rows.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date = pd.date_range('20190101',periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=date, columns=list('ABCD'))

#wtire only top two rows into csv file
print(df.head(2).to_csv("test.csv"))
```

Comment: not what I am asking since you are slicing the df beforehand. I tried that it gives me memory error because I guess pandas makes a copy..

Comment: @criticalth I don't know whether pandas head() function make a copied or not. I read pandas document, it uses for a return first N rows of dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

Does this work for you?

```
df.iloc[:N, :].to_csv()
```

Or

```
df.iloc[P:Q, :].to_csv()
```

I believe `df.iloc` generally produces references to the original dataframe rather than copying the data.

If this still doesn't work, you might also try setting the `chunksize` in the `to_csv` call. It may be that pandas is able to create the subset without using much more memory, but then it makes a complete copy of the rows written to each chunk. If the chunksize is the whole frame, you would end up copying the whole frame at that point and running out of memory.

If all else fails, you can loop through `df.iterrows()` or `df.iloc[P:Q, :].iterrows()` or `df.iloc[P:Q, :].itertuples()` and write each row using the `csv` module (possibly `writer.writerows(df.iloc[P:Q, :].itertuples()`).

Comment: still gives me a MemoryError, I upvoted since it is a usefull information

Comment: Could you try breaking it into two steps and see which one gives the memory error? I.e., `df2 = df.iloc[:N, :]` then `df2.to_csv(..., chunksize=100)`

Comment: I did. It is the df.iloc[:N, :], I tried for smaller Ns than needed and it worked but it is ugly this way. I also built a program that reads row by row and uses almost no ram but it is slow so I will do something in the middle. It is a hassle that to_csv method does not have nrows..

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17961468/3830997), `df.iloc[:N, :]` should create a view, not a copy. Nevertheless, in your case, it sounds like Pandas is trying to make a copy and then running out of memory. So you probably have to iterate over the desired section of the data frame and write the .csv file yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can select the rows index that you want to write on your CSV file like this:

```
df[df.index.isin([1, 2, ...])].to_csv('file.csv')
```

Or use this one:

```
df.loc[n:n].to_csv('file.csv')
```