# How to remove dataframe columns according to name lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

For example, now I have dataframe like this:

```
      A B C D E F G H 
row0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

A,B,C..are column names.

Now I'd like to remove columns, whose names are included in a list:

```
listrem = ['A','C','E']
```

So basically I would like to see:

```
      B D F G H
row0  2 4 6 7 8
```

How could I do that? 
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> df[[i for i in df.columns if i not in listrem]]
      B  D  F  G  H
row0  2  4  6  7  8
```

If you do not car of the order of columns:

```
df[list(set(df.columns)-set(listrem))]
```