# Python, pandas concatenate multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of csv files which I load as data frames using `pd.read_csv()`

I am currently trying to iterate through the list of csv and using the `pd.concat()` method and setting the axis parameter to one to add all the dataframes together by columns.

It is working as hoped however I am encountering the issue that since all of the data frames have the same colums names when I concatenated them I get for example ten columns all with the key "Date"

is there anyway that I can give the colums all unique names example London_Date, Berlin_Date? obviously the names being based on the name of the data frames.

Comment: if you know which columns to avoid, you can drop them right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting/Excluding sets of columns in Pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a list of keys to `concat()`, you can then individually index any column you want with the given keys like so:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df2 = df1
df3 = df1
add = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1, keys=['Group_1', 'Group_2', 'Group_3'])
print(add.Group_1.A) # or add.Group_2.B etc...
```