# evaluate every cell and return column head if not null pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, nested-loops

I have pandas.df 233 rows * 234 columns and I need to evaluate every cell and return corresponding column header if not nan, so far I wrote the following:

```
#First get a list of all column names (except column 0):

col_list=[]

for column in df.columns[1:]:
    col_list.append(column)

#Then I try to iterate through every cell and evaluate for Null
#Also a counter is initiated to take the next col_name from col_list
#when count reach 233

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    count = 0
    for x in row[1:]:
        count = count+1
        for col_name in col_list:
            if count >= 233: break
            elif str(x) != 'nan':
                print col_name
```

The code does not do exactly that, what do I need to change to get the code to break after 233 rows and go to the next col_name?

```
Example:

    Col_1   Col_2    Col_3
1    nan     13       nan
2    10      nan      nan
3    nan      2        5
4    nan     nan       4

output:      
1   Col_2
2   Col_1
3   Col_2
4   Col_3
5   Col_3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need if first column is `index` [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - it remove all `NaN`s and then get values from second level of `Multiindex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and selecting or by `Series` constructor with [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
s = df.stack().reset_index()['level_1'].rename('a')
print (s)
0    Col_2
1    Col_1
2    Col_2
3    Col_3
4    Col_3
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Or:

```
s = pd.Series(df.stack().index.get_level_values(1))
print (s)
0    Col_2
1    Col_1
2    Col_2
3    Col_3
4    Col_3
dtype: object
```

If need output as `list`:

```
L = df.stack().index.get_level_values(1).tolist()
print (L)
['Col_2', 'Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3', 'Col_3']
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.stack())
1  Col_2    13.0
2  Col_1    10.0
3  Col_2     2.0
   Col_3     5.0
4  Col_3     4.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: How to include "NaN" (or similar) for rows with only "nan" (i.e. do not skip / drop all-nan- rows)?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - use `L = df.stack(dropna=False).index.get_level_values(1).tolist()`

Comment: Doesn't work (as intended)... I have 43 rows, with only 2 rows "nan" throughout; in your original answer I get a column with 41 rows, i.e. those 2 rows are skipped; with ´dropna=False´ I get 215 rows - and none of which have "nan".   Also, **for the 2 skipped rows I'd like to see "nan" (instead of the respective column heading)** in the new column... (Why 215 ? Because in my case I have 5 columns + 43 rows...)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - How looks expected ouput if  `nan = np.nan` `df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': [nan, 10.0, nan, nan], 'Col_2': [13.0, nan, 2.0, nan], 'Col_3': [nan, nan, nan, nan]})` ?

Comment: Related / useful Q&A's: [How do I transform a Panda Dataframe from 5 columns into 1 column using column header as value to populate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404068/how-do-i-transform-a-panda-dataframe-from-5-columns-into-1-column-using-column-h), [How to collapse multiple columns into one in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103859/2153622) (bfill / fillna) and [How to transform multiple boolean columns to one column with column headers and NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095325/how-to-transform-multiple-boolean-columns-to-one-column-with-column-headers-and).

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - how looks expected ouput from DataFrame posted in my comment above?

Comment: For that 3 columns x 4 rows dataframe I get **12 entries** (*the equivalent to the 215 entries in the earlier comment above*) in that column (`print(s)`, where the modified `s` would be `s = pd.Series(df.stack(dropna=False).index.get_level_values(1))` ). - ***Instead***, I'd want to see **only 4 entries** in `s`, with the fourth being "nan". That is, for this dataframe I'd want to generate a column with four entries (i.e., rows) **Col_2, Col_1, Col_2, N/A**.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - I think you should post question. Answer should  be `df = df.assign(**{'N/A': np.where(df.isna().all(axis=1), 1, np.nan)}).stack().index.get_level_values(1).tolist()`

Comment: "Problem solved", but still need to get my head around (and my hands dirty with) ["multi-index"](https://towardsdatascience.com/working-with-multi-index-pandas-dataframes-f64d2e2c3e02); cool stuff. Happy to spawn a separate question from the comments above (soon). Many thanks to you!

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - hmmm, it is up to you. You are welcome!

Comment: Another expansion of the original problem/question: how can I exclude/ignore some non-empty columns for the above? E.g., if I want to ignore columns 'bla' and 'bla bla' from this `df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': [nan, 10.0, nan, nan], 'Col_2': [13.0, nan, 2.0, nan], 'Col_3': [nan, nan, nan, nan], 'bla':['blaa','blaa','blaa','blaa'], 'bla bla':['blaaa','blaaa','blaaa','blaaa'], })` ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - I think simpliest is remove them `df = df.drop(['bla','bla bla'], axis=1).assign(**{'N/A': np.where(df.isna().all(axis=1), 1, np.nan)}).stack().index.get_level_values(1).tolist()`

Comment: I assume I'd need to tweak the `isna().all`-part... yesterday I applied the above to a subset of the original dataframe which is okay / workable but less elegant...

Comment: wow, that was quick! I'd want to keep those columns, but only add that extra column with the column names for a subset of the columns... so no drop the 'bla'-columns completely, just ignore them for the extra column... `df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': [nan, 10.0, nan, nan], 'Col_2': [13.0, nan, 2.0, nan], 'Col_3': [nan, nan, nan, nan], 'bla':['blaa','blaa','blaa','blaa'], 'bla bla':['blaaa','blaaa','blaaa','blaaa'] })` (erroneous comma removed)

Comment: ... or is there a neat / common way to ["temporarily" drop / ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas) (those) columns?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty - in another words replace all values to `NaN`s in these columns?

Comment: nope; ignore them so they won't add to the count of items in the list (or column). just pretent they weren't there. ultimately, just want this extra column listing the column headings for col_1 .. col_3 only; this column should have the same number of rows as the original df.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty `just pretent they weren't there.` - I think it is not possible - only drop or replace content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243616/discussion-between-nutty-about-natty-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 3):

I'd use jezrael's stack solution.

However, if you're interested in `Numpy` way, which is usually faster.

```
In [4889]: np.tile(df.columns, df.shape[0])[~np.isnan(df.values.ravel())]
Out[4889]: array(['Col_2', 'Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3', 'Col_3'], dtype=object)
```

Timings

```
In [4913]: df.shape
Out[4913]: (100, 3)

In [4914]: %timeit np.tile(df.columns, df.shape[0])[~np.isnan(df.values.ravel())]
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.8 µs per loop

In [4915]: %timeit df.stack().index.get_level_values(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 335 µs per loop

In [4905]: df.shape
Out[4905]: (100000, 3)

In [4907]: %timeit np.tile(df.columns, df.shape[0])[~np.isnan(df.values.ravel())]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.98 ms per loop

In [4908]: %timeit df.stack().index.get_level_values(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```

Choose based on your need (readability, speed, maintainability etc)

Comment: Wonderful. Tile is magical :). Can't think of much faster way

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) :

```
df.dropna(axis=1).columns
```

axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}

how : {‘any’, ‘all’}

Basically you use dropna to remove the null, axis = 1 is dropping columns, and how="any" to remove is at least one in the columns is null, .columns get the remaining header.

Comment: Not sure how this is applicable, .dropna will drop the columns if nan is found but that's not the desired output.

Comment: wat I need is to evaluate every cell per row and return column name only if cell != nan

Comment: @haytham the remaining column wouldn't be the columns where cell != nan ?

Comment: @haytham also is it's 'nan' and not NaN, you can use df.replace("nan", numpy.nan)