# How do I transform a Panda Dataframe from 5 columns into 1 column using column header as value to populate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

This is data collected from a survey where there was a radio button to select from 1 of 5 choices. What is stored in the column is a simple 1 as a flag to say it was selected.

I am wanting to end up with a single column with the column headers as the values.  Someone suggested using the IDXMAX method on my dataframe, but when I looked at the docs I couldn't really figure out how to apply it. It does look like it would be useful for this though...

I have a dataframe:

```
 old = pd.DataFrame({'a FINSEC_SA' : [1,'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',1,'NaN'],
 'b FINSEC_A' : ['NaN',1,'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
 'c FINSEC_NO' : ['NaN','NaN',1,'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
 'd FINSEC_D' : ['NaN','NaN','NaN',1,'NaN','NaN',1],
 'e FINSEC_SD' : ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',1,'NaN','NaN']})
```

[image]

I would like to end up with a dataframe like this:

```
new = pd.DataFrame({'Financial Security':['a FINSEC_SA','b FINSEC_A',
'c FINSEC_NO','d FINSEC_D','e FINSEC_SD','a FINSEC_SA','d FINSEC_D']})
```

[image]

I only have about 65k rows of data so performance is not top of list for me.  I am most interested in learning a good way to do this - that is hopefully fairly simple.  It would be really nice if the idxmax does this fairly easily.

Comment: The range of different answers, presumably from pandas user with varying experience levels, repays a full reading, as it shows approaches of many levels of sophistication.

Comment: Thanks to all who've answered.  In creating the 1st dataframe above - I didn't realise what I was doing by creating 'NaN' as a string vs as a numeric value. Clearly it would've been better to create it as my data actually is - using NaN the proper way...  I'm kind of new to python at this point and are just figuring some things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

idxmax can only work with numerics. So first, we need to convert 'NaN' (a string) to np.NaN (a numeric value). Then we can convert each column into a numerical series:

```
old = old.replace('NaN', np.NaN)
old = old.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

alternatively you can do this in one line with:

```
old = old.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

finally, we can run idxmax. All you have to do is specify the axis. axis=1 to get the position of 1 (highest value) in each row, axis=0 to get the position of 1 in each column

```
new = old.idxmax(axis=1)
```

You can run the code in one line (if you don't need a copy of old after this):

```
new = old.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').idxmax(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `idxmax` followed by `reset_index` to achieve this.

```
df = old.idxmax(axis=1).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1).rename(columns={0:'Financial'})

print(df)

      Financial
0   a FINSEC_SA
1   b FINSEC_A
2   c FINSEC_NO
3   d FINSEC_D
4   e FINSEC_SD
5   a FINSEC_SA
6   d FINSEC_D
```

**Explanation:** 
1. `idxmax` select max. value row wise across columns. 
2. `drop` drops the unwanted column followed by removing `duplicate` values.
3. Finally, we `rename` the column as required.

Comment: I wish you'd left your original answer in for comparison rather than editing it. I'm sure many people could have learned the value of trying different approaches, so it would add to the diversity of the question, so to speak.

Comment: I later realised that was incorrect answer. I simply stacked the data so to get original column names. But, the answer required column names based on non-na values.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below, I created a function to check NaN separately, as I think in real data you will have np.NaN and not 'NaN' (strings). You can modify the string accordingly

```
def isNaN(num):
    return num == 'NaN'

def getval(x):
    if not isNaN(x['a FINSEC_SA']) : return 'a FINSEC_SA'
    if not isNaN(x['b FINSEC_A']) : return 'b FINSEC_A'
    if not isNaN(x['c FINSEC_NO']) : return 'c FINSEC_NO'
    if not isNaN(x['d FINSEC_D']) : return 'd FINSEC_D'
    if not isNaN(x['e FINSEC_SD']) : return 'e FINSEC_SD'


old.apply(getval, axis=1)
```

This is readable but not efficient answer. Melt functionality can be used to get the same answer in much more efficient manner -

```
old['id'] = old.index
new = pd.melt(old, id_vars= 'id', var_name = 'Financial')
new = new[new['value'] != 'NaN'].drop('value', axis=1).sort_index(axis=0)
```

Comment: While this answer is a creditable effort, and works, it has deficiencies. One issue, for example, is how to cope with additional columns. This solution requires code changes, others would not. Another is its likely poor timings against solutions using `pandas` primitives.