# How to collapse multiple columns into one in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe filled with users and categories, but multiple columns for those categories.

```
|   user  |       category    | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| ------  | ------------------| -----| ---- | ---- |
| user 1  | c1                |   3  |  NA  | None |
| user 1  | c2                |   NA |  4   | None |
| user 1  | c3                |   NA |  NA  | 7    |
| user 2  | c1                |   5  |  NA  | None |
| user 2  | c2                |   NA |  7   | None |
| user 2  | c3                |   NA |  NA  | 2    |
```

I want to get it so the values are compressed into a single column.

```
|   user  |       category    | value|
| ------  | ------------------| -----| 
| user 1  | c1                |   3  | 
| user 1  | c2                |   4  | 
| user 1  | c3                |   7  |
| user 2  | c1                |   5  | 
| user 2  | c2                |   7  | 
| user 2  | c3                |   2  |
```

Ultimately, to get a matrix like the following:

```
np.array([[3, 4, 7], [5, 7, 2]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) to backfill values over selected columns.

```
val_cols = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']

df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df[val_cols].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce')

print(df)

    user0 category  val1  val2  val3  value
0  user 1       c1   3.0   NaN  None    3.0
1  user 1       c2   NaN   4.0  None    4.0
2  user 1       c3   NaN   NaN  7       7.0
3  user 2       c1   5.0   NaN  None    5.0
4  user 2       c2   NaN   7.0  2       7.0
5  user 2       c3   NaN   NaN  2       2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

- Start by setting the index with `['user', 'category']`
- Follow that up with looking up where the first non-null values are
- Construct a pandas Series with the same index you set and the new values you looked up

---

```
d = df.set_index(['user', 'category'])
pd.Series(d.lookup(d.index, d.isna().idxmin(1)), d.index).reset_index(name='value')

     user category value
0  user 1       c1     3
1  user 1       c2     4
2  user 1       c3     7
3  user 2       c1     5
4  user 2       c2     7
5  user 2       c3     2
```

You can skip the resetting of the index and unstack to get your final result

```
d = df.set_index(['user', 'category'])
pd.Series(d.lookup(d.index, d.isna().idxmin(1)), d.index).unstack()

category c1 c2 c3
user             
user 1    3  4  7
user 2    5  7  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `fillna(0)` (`df2 = df.fillna(0)`) and use `|` operator.

Convert to `int` first

```
df2.loc[:, ['val1','val2','val3']] = df2[['val1','val2','val3']].astype(int)
```

Then

```
df2['val4'] = df2.val1.values | df2.val2.values | df2.val3.values
```