# How to transform multiple boolean columns to one column with column headers and NaN?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A      B      C
False  True   False
False  False  False
True   True   False
False  False  True
False  True   False
```

And I need to obtain something like this:

```
Total
B  
NaN
A
C
B
```

I tried with:

```
df[["A", "B", "C"]].idxmax(1)
```

but is not returning the NaN, is returning A in place of NaN.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, `idxmax` with `series.where` and `df.any`

```
df.idxmax(1).where(df.any(1))
#or np.where(df.any(1),df.idxmax(1),np.nan)
```

---

```
0      B
1    NaN
2      A
3      C
4      B
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check for `any()` being **True**

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""A      B      C
False  True   False
False  False  False
True   True   False
False  False  True
False  True   False"""), sep="\s+")

pd.Series(np.where(df.loc[:,["A","B","C"]].any(axis=1), df.loc[:,["A","B","C"]].idxmax(axis=1), np.nan), name="Total")
```

#### output

```
0      B
1    NaN
2      A
3      C
4      B
Name: Total, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this by checking the `index` of `True`. You have to be aware that `index` can throw a `ValueError`.

```py
data = '''
A      B      C
False  True   False
False  False  False
True   True   False
False  False  True
False  True   False
'''

def safe_index(arr, val):
    try: return arr.index(val)
    except ValueError: return -1

def calculate_totals(data):
    lines = data.strip().split('\n')
    keys = lines[0].split()
    return list(
        map(lambda i: keys[i] if i != -1 else 'NaN',
        [safe_index(line.split(), 'True') for line in lines[1:]]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n'.join(['Total'] + calculate_totals(data)))
```