# Select two sets of columns by column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take the `DataFrame` in the answer of [Loc vs. iloc vs. ix vs. at vs. iat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757389/loc-vs-iloc-vs-ix-vs-at-vs-iat/47098873#47098873) for example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'age':[30, 2, 12, 4, 32, 33, 69],
 'color':['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'gray', 'black', 'red'],
 'food':['Steak', 'Lamb', 'Mango', 'Apple', 'Cheese', 'Melon', 'Beans'],
 'height':[165, 70, 120, 80, 180, 172, 150],
 'score':[4.6, 8.3, 9.0, 3.3, 1.8, 9.5, 2.2],
 'state':['NY', 'TX', 'FL', 'AL', 'AK', 'TX', 'TX']},
 index=['Jane', 'Nick', 'Aaron', 'Penelope', 'Dean', 'Christina', 'Cornelia']
)
```

Now I want *all columns except 'food' and 'height'*.

I thought something like `df.loc[:,['age':'color', 'score':'state']]` would work, but Python returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

I am aware of that there is one way to work around: `df.drop(columns = ['food', 'height'])`. However, in my real life situation, I have hundreds of columns to be dropped. Typing out all column names is so inefficient.

I am expecting something similar with `dplyr::select(df, -(food:height))` or `dplyr::select(df, age:color, score:state)` in R language.

Also have read [Selecting/Excluding sets of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas).

Comment: Can you please explain why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas did not work for you? It seems to have the solution to your problem.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, Sorry but I don't see how it would work for me. The accepted answer of that thread gives answer like `df.drop(columns = ['food', 'height'])` like I mentioned in my post. Also all the answers there seem to need all the column names to be explicitly typed. Yet I have written in my post clearly that the column names I want to drop are too many to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find all columns lying between `food` and `height` (inclusive).

```
c = df.iloc[-1:0].loc[:, 'food':'height'].columns
```

Next, filter with `difference`/`isin`/`setdiff1d` -

```
df[df.columns.difference(c)]
```

Or,

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(c)]
```

Or,

```
df[np.setdiff1d(df.columns, c)]
```

```
           age  color  score state
Jane        30   blue    4.6    NY
Nick         2  green    8.3    TX
Aaron       12    red    9.0    FL
Penelope     4  white    3.3    AL
Dean        32   gray    1.8    AK
Christina   33  black    9.5    TX
Cornelia    69    red    2.2    TX
```

Comment: @jezrael Maybe... I didn't look this time. If it is, I'll delete, no prob

Comment: last link in question of OP.

Comment: Thanks but I really need a solution which is more general and *does not* need to type all the column names explicitly. Also, the `~`makes me even confused. Is that something like `not` and `!`? Why is Python so inconsistent in "not" expression?

Comment: @ytu Also, the ~ is how you perform negation on dataframe and series. It is an overloaded version of the bitwise NOT operator, but semantically means something else.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I really appreciate your help. Now `df[df.columns.difference(c)]` and `df[np.setdiff1d(df.columns, c)]` works for me, but `df[~df.columns.isin(c)]` gives me `ValueError: Item wrong length 6 instead of 7.` Would you mind checking?

Comment: @ytu Oh, my bad. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First get positions of columns names by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and then use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for join all slicers together:

```
a = np.r_[df.columns.get_loc('age'):df.columns.get_loc('color')+1, 
          df.columns.get_loc('score'):df.columns.get_loc('state')+1]

df = df.iloc[:, a]
print (df)
           age  color  score state
Jane        30   blue    4.6    NY
Nick         2  green    8.3    TX
Aaron       12    red    9.0    FL
Penelope     4  white    3.3    AL
Dean        32   gray    1.8    AK
Christina   33  black    9.5    TX
Cornelia    69    red    2.2    TX
```

Answer (score 0):

One option for flexible column selection is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.select_columns(slice('age', 'color'), slice('score', 'state'))

           age  color  score state
Jane        30   blue    4.6    NY
Nick         2  green    8.3    TX
Aaron       12    red    9.0    FL
Penelope     4  white    3.3    AL
Dean        32   gray    1.8    AK
Christina   33  black    9.5    TX
Cornelia    69    red    2.2    TX

df.select_columns(slice('food', 'height'), invert = True)

           age  color  score state
Jane        30   blue    4.6    NY
Nick         2  green    8.3    TX
Aaron       12    red    9.0    FL
Penelope     4  white    3.3    AL
Dean        32   gray    1.8    AK
Christina   33  black    9.5    TX
Cornelia    69    red    2.2    TX
```