# Dropping / Keeping Dataframe columns

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe imported from a csv file using Pandas read_csv. Its shape is 735, 36. I need to drop the last 33 columns - keeping the first 3. 
The columns are `'code'`,`'proc'`, `'All procedures'`

I have tried all the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319200/11795964)

Whatever I do I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

For example:

```py
df1=df[['code','proc', 'All procedures']]
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-350994f9b7c6> in <module>
----> 1 df[['code','proc', 'All procedures']]

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

I have started again. The ‘bool object is not subscriptable’ error has gone away, I  think df had been overwritten.

I am  trying to use some publicly available data on hospital activity and extract data from it.I am a neurosurgeon so you may have to be patient. The data is here 
https://files.digital.nhs.uk/77/0C8B3F/hosp-epis-stat-admi-proc-2018-19-tab.xlsx

I want to extract the first three columns of the CSV in the code below, and output as excel.

My new problem is that I can’t extract the columns 'proc' and  ‘All procedures’.

Here is my working

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pygal
import os
import webbrowser
```

This imports one tab of the spreadsheet which I have converted to csv and renamed

```
df = pd.read_csv('neuro_spine_craino_just_all4.csv')
df.head(5)
```

```
code    proc    All procedures  Main procedure  Male    Female  Gender Unknown  Mean age    Age 0   Age 1-4 ... Age 65-69   Age 70-74   Age 75-79   Age 80-84   Age 85-89   Age 90+ Day case    Emergency   Elective    Other
```

0   A01.1   Hemispherectomy 20  20  8   12  0   11.0    0   7   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   A01.2   Total lobectomy of brain    53  53  37  16  0   40.0    1   1   ... 4   4   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2   A01.3   Partial lobectomy of brain  174 148 95  79  0   41.0    1   5   ... 12  14  3   1   0   0   0   1   1   0
3   A01.8   Other specified major excision of tissue of brain   20  15  12  8   0   34.0    1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   A01.9   Unspecified major excision of tissue of brain   3   3   0   3   0   39.0    0   0   ...

```
df.info
```

code                                             proc   All procedures
\
0    A01.1                                    Hemispherectomy             20
1    A01.2                           Total lobectomy of brain             53
2    A01.3                         Partial lobectomy of brain            174
3    A01.8  Other specified major excision of tissue of brain             20
4    A01.9      Unspecified major excision of tissue of brain              3

```
df.columns
```

Index(['code', 'proc', 'All procedures', 'Main procedure', 'Male', 'Female',
       'Gender Unknown', ' Mean age ', 'Age 0', 'Age 1-4', 'Age 5-9',
       'Age 10-14', 'Age 15', 'Age 16', 'Age 17', 'Age 18', 'Age 19',
       'Age 20-24', 'Age 25-29', 'Age 30-34', 'Age 35-39', 'Age 40-44',
       'Age 45-49', 'Age 50-54', 'Age 55-59', 'Age 60-64', 'Age 65-69',
       'Age 70-74', 'Age 75-79', 'Age 80-84', 'Age 85-89', 'Age 90+',
       'Day case', 'Emergency', 'Elective', 'Other'],
      dtype='object')

```
df['code'], ['proc'], ['All procedures']
```

This will only give me the first 
column and index.

(0      A01.1
 1      A01.2
 2      A01.3
 3      A01.8
 4      A01.9
 5      A02.1
 6      A02.2
 7      A02.3
 8      A02.4
 9      A02.5
 10     A02.6
 11     A02.7
 12     A02.8
 13     A02.9
 14     A03.1
 15     A03.2
 16     A03.3

Comment: What is `df`, from the error it seems is a boolean.

Comment: Can you set up an example to show this failing on https://repl.it? Doesn't look like `df` is actually of Type DataFrame

Comment: Specifically, we need a snippet of how you create df with dummy data. Not the whole df = pd.read_csv(...) but a sample that includes data, like `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]})`. I would refresh your notebook and start from scratch in case `df` got overwritten at some point executing other cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract those columns from the dataframe you can do either

`result = df[['code', 'proc', 'All procedures']]`

or

`result = df.loc[:, ['code', 'proc', 'All procedures']]`

See pandas docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) for info on this - known as slicing

Your issue was not including the columns in one list passed into the dataframe - only `'code'` was passed into the actual `df` selector