# How to slice a dataframe with specific column names + range of columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given any pandas dataframe.
I want to select columns A, B and F:Z

I have tried to do it `df.loc[:, ['A','B','F':'Z']]` but it didn't work.
Please advise how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do two slice then combine

```
df.loc[:, ['A','B']].join(df.loc[:,'F':'Z'])
```

And side solution change all name to position then we can do

```
df.iloc[:,np.r_[1,2,5:999]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Please advise if it's possible to do it with `df.columns not in ['C', 'D', 'E']` in some way?

Comment: @SteveS `out = df.drop(['C','D','E'],axis=1)`

Comment: The  `df[df.columns.difference(['C', 'D', 'E'])]` is also an option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas