# Spliting dataframe - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

How can I select the columns in the dataframe which the column names is not belong to a list?

For example:

I have the following input and I would like to select columns which columns names does not belong to b

```
#input
a=pd.DataFrame({
    '0':[10,10,10,10,10],
    '1':[2,3,8,10,11],
    '2':[0,1,2,3,4],
    '3':[13,12,14,14,13],
    '4':[15,13,17,18,19],
    '5':[10,2,3,4,6]
})
b=[2,3,4]

#output
output=pd.DataFrame({
    '0':[10,10,10,10,10],
    '1':[2,3,8,10,11],
    '5':[10,2,3,4,6]
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting/excluding sets of columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940743/selecting-excluding-sets-of-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Here the catch is that your elements in `b` are `integers` while `a` columns are `strings`:

**you can convert your b values to string then**:

```
#input
a=pd.DataFrame({
    '0':[10,10,10,10,10],
    '1':[2,3,8,10,11],
    '2':[0,1,2,3,4],
    '3':[13,12,14,14,13],
    '4':[15,13,17,18,19],
    '5':[10,2,3,4,6]
})
b=[2,3,4]

new_b = [str(x) for x in b]

a[a.columns.difference(new_b)]  # or a[a.columns.difference(map(str, b))]

#Output
    0   1   5
0   10  2   10
1   10  3   2
2   10  8   3
3   10  10  4
4   10  11  6
```

One more way is:

```
a[a.columns[~a.columns.isin(new_b)]]

    0   1   5
0   10  2   10
1   10  3   2
2   10  8   3
3   10  10  4
4   10  11  6
```

Comment: I really like your solution. +1 `a[a.columns.difference(map(str, b))]`

Comment: Thank you @ScottBoston... I am learning...

Answer (score 1):

Convert `b` to strings, Iterate over `a.columns` and check which element in `a.columns` is not in `b`

```py
a=pd.DataFrame({
    '0':[10,10,10,10,10],
    '1':[2,3,8,10,11],
    '2':[0,1,2,3,4],
    '3':[13,12,14,14,13],
    '4':[15,13,17,18,19],
    '5':[10,2,3,4,6]
})
})
b=['2','3','4']
b = [str(x) for x in b]

chosen_columns = [e for e in a.columns if e not in b]

output = a[chosen_columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use drop and create a new dataframe:

```
b = [str(i) for i in b]
output = a.drop(columns=b)


# Output
    0   1   5
0  10   2  10
1  10   3   2
2  10   8   3
3  10  10   4
4  10  11   6
```