# Delete pandas column with no name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know to delete a column I can use `df = df.drop('column_name', 1)`, but how would I remove a column just by indexing which column it is? As in without inserting the name?

Sorry if this question has been repeated I can't seem to find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32909107/3130926

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can delete column by index `i`

`df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)`

Adapted from duplicate question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20301769/3006366