# How to drop duplicate multiindex column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Been searching the net, but I cannot find any resource on deleting duplicate multiindex column name.

Given a multiindex as below

```
      level1                    
      level2                    
           A   B   C   B   A   C
ONE       11  12  13  11  12  13
TWO       21  22  23  21  22  23
THREE     31  32  33  31  32  33
```

Drop duplicated `B` and `C`

Expected output

```
      level1                    
      level2                    
           A   B   C   A
ONE       11  12  13  11
TWO       21  22  23  21
THREE     31  32  33  31
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 21, 31],
               'B': [12, 22, 32],
               'C': [13, 23, 33]},
              index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [11, 21, 31],
               'A': [12, 22, 32],
               'C': [13, 23, 33]},
              index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['level1'],['level2'],df.columns ])
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['level1'],['level2'],df2.columns ])
df=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
```

-Drop by [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297317/python-dataframe-pandas-drop-column-using-int/63641601#63641601) not working

Comment: the drop index function cant tell which to drop, since they have the same names. ``df.iloc[:, :-2]`` fixes it; I would however, caution against using same names for columns

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This happen due to the fact several `df` been concatenated

Comment: But, why do you want the duplicated column names for `A`? I'm afraid, normal dropping is not going to work for your use case, you need to have some custom dropping mechanism.

Comment: This is a simple example. Please ignore the need of maintaining duplicated `A` @ThePyGuy

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, unfortunately, your suggestion is not robust for not symmetry column orientation. I have some changes to the post to reflect this

Comment: `df.T.drop_duplicates().T`?

Comment: Somehow this is what I need @AnuragDabas. But as per the expected output here, I will removed the `A`. But, something that I can tweak on for real use case

Comment: Why don't you just provide your real case example?

Comment: so you want to include duplicated A as well?

Comment: @Anurag, As per OP, only remove duplicated 'B` and `C`

Comment: @mozway, I can tweak based on Anurag recommendation. The example given is the closes to real use case.

Comment: Well, maybe, but if you had provided a your real case example with the expected output, this would probably have saved the contributors quite some time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
mask=(df.T.duplicated() | (df.columns.get_level_values(2).isin(['A','D'])))
```

Finally:

```
df=df.loc[:, mask]
#OR
#df=df.T.loc[mask].T
```

Comment: It will be interesting to generalize this suggestion for larger set of column at the second level.Say for example,at the second level we have `A`,`B`,`C` ,`D`, and we want to remove both `B` and `C` and maintain both `A` and `D`.

Comment: @balandongiv In that case use `isin()` updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Can't you directly do `df.loc[:, mask]`? +1

Comment: @balandongiv kindly check the updated answer **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Adaptation to `df.T.drop_duplicates().T` by `Anurag Dabas`.

Select only  unique column and its value

```
drop_col=['B','C']
drop_single=[df.loc [:, (slice ( None ), slice ( None ), DCOL)].T.drop_duplicates().T for DCOL in drop_col]
```

Drop the columns from the `df`

```
df=df.drop ( drop_col, axis=1, level=2 )
```

Combine everything to get the intended output

```
df=pd.concat([df,*drop_single],axis=1)
```

Complete solution

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 21, 31],
               'B': [12, 22, 32],
               'C': [13, 23, 33]},
              index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [11, 21, 31],
               'A': [12, 22, 32],
               'C': [13, 23, 33]},
              index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['level1'],['level2'],df.columns ])
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['level1'],['level2'],df2.columns ])
df=pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
drop_col=['B','C']
drop_single=[df.loc [:, (slice ( None ), slice ( None ), DCOL)].iloc [:, 1] for DCOL in drop_col]

df=df.drop ( drop_col, axis=1, level=2 )
df_unique=pd.concat(drop_single,axis=1)
df=pd.concat([df,df_unique],axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: But still, the suggestion by Anurag is much more compact https://stackoverflow.com/a/68690202/6446053

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
# Drop last 2 columns of dataframe
df.drop(columns=df.columns[-2:], 
        axis=1, 
        inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Mohammad, but this suggestion is not robust for not symmetry column orientation

Comment: Im down voting this as this does not solve the issue