# how to remove columns using indexes

Tags: python, pandas

How do I remove columns starting from a certain index to another, I need to remove **columns** from 1950 to 2004?

I tried running this but it didn’t work

```
test = df.drop(df.iloc[:, 1:55],  axis = 1)
```

Comment: `df.drop(list(range(1950,2005)),  axis=1, errors='ignore')`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671822/1560708 <-- this does not solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python dataframe pandas drop column using int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297317/python-dataframe-pandas-drop-column-using-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column names are integers:

```
test = df.drop(list(range(1950,2005)), axis=1, errors='ignore')
```

For strings:

```
test = df.drop(list(map(str, range(1950,2005))), axis=1, errors='ignore')
```