# How to delete a column from a data frame with pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, io

I read my data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/file.tsv', header=0, delimiter='\t')
print df
```

and get:

```
          id    text
0    361.273    text1...
1    374.350    text2...
2    374.350    text3...
```

How can I delete the `id` column from the above data frame?. I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/file.tsv', header=0, delimiter='\t')
print df.drop('id', 1)
```

But it raises this exception:

```
ValueError: labels ['id'] not contained in axis
```

Comment: What does `df.columns` report as the column names? Perhaps there is a space in the column name?

Comment: `Index([u'id    opinion'], dtype='object')` Thanks for the response

Comment: One thing to note, do you really need to delete the column? You can select just the columns of interest from the df by doing `df['text']` or more generally `df[some_list]`, additionally if you never wanted it in the first place then don't load it `df = pd.read_csv('/path/file.tsv', header=0, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0])`

Comment: I want to delete it, too. But it is a matter of presentation, for when you actually make the report. Is better to pivot the frame before or just delete de column ?

Comment: Just for completeness `df.drop(['id'],1)` works

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**To actually delete the column**

`del df['id']` or `df.drop('id', 1)` should have worked if the passed column matches exactly

However, if you don't need to delete the column then you can just select the column of interest like so:

```
In [54]:

df['text']
Out[54]:
0    text1
1    text2
2    textn
Name: text, dtype: object
```

If you never wanted it in the first place then you pass a list of cols to `read_csv` as a param `usecols`:

```
In [53]:
import io
temp="""id    text
363.327    text1
366.356    text2
37782    textn"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), delimiter='\s+', usecols=['text'])
df
Out[53]:
    text
0  text1
1  text2
2  textn
```

Regarding your error it's because `'id'` is not in your columns or that it's spelt differently or has whitespace. To check this look at the output from `print(df.columns.tolist())` this will output a list of the columns and will show if you have any leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: The question was how to delete a column.  It is a valid question which is not addressed in this answer.  I was not the downvoter.

Comment: @TimD the context of the question is that OP wanted to remove a column they were not interested in, my answer shows that firstly this isn't necessary if you just want to use a specific column or that you could in fact just not read that column or only read the columns of interest and the OP accepted the answer

Comment: you have indeed solved the problem that the OP had, which is evident from context.  I landed on this question from a Google search looking for a way to remove column.  In _my_ context, this answer does not help me since I don't know _a priori_ which columns I will need until after I have read them. You may have solved the OP problem, but I bet subsequent visitors to the page will be looking for `DataFrame.drop()` and upvoting answers that present that.

Comment: @TimD I've added the additional information now plus how to debug this issue

Answer (score 54):

`df.drop(colname, axis=1)` (or `del df[colname]`) is the correct method to use to delete a column.

If a `ValueError` is raised, it means the column name is not exactly what you think it is.

Check `df.columns` to see what Pandas thinks are the names of the columns.

Answer (score 38):

The best way to delete a column in pandas is to use [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop('column_name', axis=1)
```

where `1` is the *axis* number (`0` for rows and `1` for columns.)

To delete the column without having to reassign `df` you can do:

```
df.drop('column_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Finally, to drop by column *number* instead of by column *label*, try this.
To delete, e.g. the 1st, 2nd and 4th columns:

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1)  # df.columns is zero-based pd.Index
```

Exceptions:

If a wrong column number or label is requested an error will be thrown.
To check the number of columns use `df.shape[1]` or `len(df.columns.values)` and to check the column labels use `df.columns.values`.

An exception would be raised 
answer was based on @LondonRob's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-using-python-del) and left here to help future visitors of this page.