# How to properly delete a column in dataframe (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter

I cannot delete a column from `csv` using pandas. I tried to delete it in many ways using different axis, del function but it doesn't work. Does somebody know why ?

Here is my pandas.head()

```
age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"
0  58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143...

1  44;"technician";"single";"secondary";"no";29;"...

2  33;"entrepreneur";"married";"secondary";"no";2...

3  47;"blue-collar";"married";"unknown";"no";1506...

4  33;"unknown";"single";"unknown";"no";1;"no";"n...
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas  
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv')
print(df.head())
df = df.drop(['day', 'poutcome'], axis=1)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/BankMarketinData/main.py", line 21, in 
    main()
  File "/home/administrator/PycharmProjects/BankMarketinData/main.py", line 19, in main
    df = df.drop(['day', 'poutcome'], axis=1)
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3697, in drop
    errors=errors)
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3111, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3143, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "/home/administrator/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4404, in drop
    '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: "['day' 'poutcome'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: I think you have quotes in your column headers.    try `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('\"')`

Comment: Please show df.head().to_dict() maybe you have whitespace ?

Comment: Posted answer below. Tested it on a sample dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a column from a data frame with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035839/how-to-delete-a-column-from-a-data-frame-with-pandas)

Comment: My guess is that your column labels are quoted, e.g., `"day"`

Comment: Oh that's the output of `pands.head()`, you didn't properly parse the data into a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

So it's a pretty simple problem. First of all, i would advise you to use `delimiter` whenever you're dealing with `tabular` data. Now let's focus on your problem, so you're reading your `dataframe` like this:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv')
df = df.drop(['day', 'poutcome'], axis=1)
```

Now your `column` names contain `""` in them. So the name of your columns is `"day"`  & `"poutcome"` not `day` & `poutcome`. Remember these `double quotes` `""` are part of your column name. So you should write something like this to drop these columns:

```
df = df.drop(['"day"', '"poutcome"'], axis=1)
```

I hope this helps you. If you've any further questions, let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv', sep=';')
df.columns = [col.replace('"', '') for col in df.columns]
df.drop(columns=['day','poutcome'], inplace=True)
```

As you can see from the follow up comments, your issues are that you have the wrong separator when bringing in your csv file. Then, you need to remove the quotation marks that are in your column names so you can drop those columns.

Comment: you need to remove the quotation marks from your column names. either in the csv or in python, then it will work.

Comment: print out the column names and make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Index(['age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"'], dtype='object')
Index(['age;job;marital;education;default;balance;housing;loan;contact;day;month;duration;campaign;pdays;previous;poutcome;y'], dtype='object') and error from previus comment

Comment: It is reading all of your columns as one it looks like. I will update the code above.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: The column names contain "" . So the column names are "day" & "poutcome". Not day & poutcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop them one by one, or use a loop to drop multiple columns. You do need to make sure that those column names are the ones in the dataframe. It looks like from your question your column name are wrapped in "". Make sure to define your delimiter correctly when reading in the dataframe also. When using read_csv it will default to ',', but in this case it is ';'.

One by one

```
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv', sep=';')
df = df.drop(['day'], axis=1)
df = df.drop(['poutcome'], axis=1)
```

Loop

```
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv', sep=';')
Drop_list = ['day','poutcome']
for column in Drop_list: 
    df = df.drop([column], axis=1)
```

Test I used for question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.head(5)

              A         B         C         D
    0  0.860680 -0.408577  0.727530 -0.119050
    1 -1.140042  0.241970 -1.509257 -0.303601
    2  0.811929  0.146228  2.102941  0.772328
    3 -0.590157  0.753719  0.220592 -0.563953
    4  0.031505 -0.521978  0.410718 -0.325865

Drop_list = ['A','B','C']
for column in Drop_list:
    df = df.drop([column], axis=1)
df.head(5)

          D
0 -0.119050
1 -0.303601
2  0.772328
3 -0.563953
4 -0.325865
```

Comment: his issue is that he has quotation marks in his column names

Comment: this, tested code u used work for me, but on my csv file it don't work

Comment: what is your delimiter when you use pd.read_csv? When you are reading the dataframe in use df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv', sep=';'). It also looks like you didn't define your header row correctly.

Comment: you are right, after added sep=';', it work, thank you for help :)