# Pandas drop index type columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop multiple columns from `pandas.DataFrame` and can't do it.

```
In [10]: object_columns = X.select_dtypes(['object']).columns

In [10]: type(object_columns)

Out[10]: pandas.core.index.Index

In [11]: X = X.drop(object_columns, inplace=True, axis=1)

ValueError: labels ['VAR_0001' 'VAR_0005' 'VAR_0044' 'VAR_0073'] not contained in axis
```

I change code and it doesn't help:

```
In [12]: X = X.drop(X[object_columns], inplace=True, axis=1)

KeyError: "['VAR_0001' 'VAR_0005' 'VAR_0044' 'VAR_0073'] not in index"
```

Can anybody explain what I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try dropping by column numbers such as df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,3]], axis=1, inplace=True) as shown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe - if only to see if that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do `X.drop(object_columns, inplace=True, axis=1)`

by passing `inplace=True` it operates on the object and returns nothing so you shouldn't be assigning it back, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop).

So you don't need:

```
X = X.drop(object_columns, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

just

```
X.drop(object_columns, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

if you passed `inplace=False` which is the default:

```
X = X.drop(object_columns, inplace=False, axis=1)
```

then it would have worked

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You passed `inplace=True` this means it doesn't return a copy of the modified df, rather it operates on the original df and returns nothing so you don't need `X = X.drop(object_columns, inplace=True, axis=1)`, just `X.drop(object_columns, inplace=True, axis=1)`

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following

If you want to remove "Index" column use

`X.reset_index()`

here removed index column will be added as a new column.

If you want to just delete index columns use

`X.reset_index(drop=True)`

If you just want to drop some columns but not only one use the following

`X.drop(['list of column names, seperated by comma'], inplace=True, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `level` in `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()` to drop specific index column.