# pandas group by ALL functionality?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm using the `pandas groupby+agg` functionality to generate nice reports

```
aggs_dict = {'a':['mean', 'std'], 'b': 'size'}
df.groupby('year').agg(aggs_dict)
```

I would like to use the same `aggs_dict` on the entire dataframe as a single group, with no division to years, something like:

```
df.groupall().agg(aggs_dict)
```

or:

```
df.agg(aggs_dict)
```

But couldn't find any elegant way to do it.. Note that in my real code `aggs_dict` is quite complex so it's rather cumbersome to do:

```
df.a.mean()
df.a.std()
df.b.size()
....
```

am I missing something simple and nice?

Comment: @ayhan IIUC, it's the opposite - if the entire index would be one big duplicate, that would work here. The question is about an aggregation for the entire df as a group, not for each of the rows.

Comment: @AmiTavory Yeah I noticed that after your answer. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ami Tavory's answer is a great way to do it but just in case you wanted a solution that doesn't require creating new columns and deleting them afterwards you could do something like:

```
df.groupby([True]*len(df)).agg(aggs_dict)
```

Comment: wow! exactly what I wanted (cumbersome notation, but I'm used to that from pandas :)

Comment: Nice answer! <padding>

Answer (score 28):

You could also use a function to directly group on:

```
 df.groupby(lambda x: True).agg(aggs_dict)
```

Comment: I think this answer is much better than provided earlier by @bunji (below)

Answer (score 7):

You could add a dummy column:

```
df['dummy'] = 1
```

Then groupby + agg on it:

```
df.groupby('dummy').agg(aggs_dict)
```

and then [delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe) when you're done.