# deleting pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete the column of a pandas dataframe and I get the following error: `ValueError: labels [' 5'] not contained in axis`. However my `print df.columns` returns`Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64')`. See bellow the code as well:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),skiprows=186,sep=";",header=None)
#df.drop(' 5', inplace=True)
b= df.columns.tolist()
print df.columns
```

Comment: Your column are integers, you are dropping a string '5', try `df.drop(5, axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: Maybe you should try `5` instead of `' 5'`.

Comment: thank you John, that was willy of me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete column from pandas DataFrame by column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-by-column-name)

Answer (score -1):

```py
df=df.drop(0,axis=1) #to  delete/remove single columns
df=df.drop([0,2,3,4,5,6],axis=1) #To delete columns at 0 2,3,4,5,6
df.drop(columns=['B', 'C']) #to Delete columns by name
```

Comment: Yes, please accept my apology, I missed that. However, you could improve the answer by explaining what OP misunderstood about the syntax and its meanings, if you do that in prose, you could prevent others from also making my mistake. (The downvote is not by me by the way.)