# pandas.dataframe.pop for all names in a array

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to remove a list of columns from a pandas.DataFrame. I've created a list through

```
diff = df1.difference(df2)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
for name in diff:
    dataframe.pop(name)
```

Is there a way to apply the pop function in a vectorized way with all names in the diff index array?

Thanks all for the help!

Regards,
Jan

Comment: `dataframe.drop(diff, axis=1)` - will drop all columns belonging to `diff` list

Comment: Are you just trying to some columns?

Answer (score 1):

as MaxU said, cleanest way to do it is

```
dataframe.drop(diff, axis=1)
```

the `.pop()` method returns the series you are poping, which is not time effective if you only want to delete the column

also, you coulduse the `del` method which maps to the python magic method `df.__delitem__('column')`. I would not recommend that.

you can read this great [SO answer to learn more about those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: oh yes! that is exactly what i wanted. Had the wrong function all along.