# Why does using df.drop to delete a column drop the whole dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-using-python-del) I tried this to delete two columns from a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

A_csv = """cases,population,country,year,type,count
745,19987071,Afghanistan,1999,population,19987071
2666,20595360,Afghanistan,2000,population,20595360
37737,172006362,Brazil,1999,population,172006362
80488,174504898,Brazil,2000,population,174504898
212258,1272915272,China,1999,population,1272915272
213766,1280428583,China,2000,population,1280428583"""

with StringIO(A_csv) as fp:
    A = pd.read_csv(fp)
print(A)
print()
dropcols = ["type", "count"]

A = A.drop(dropcols, axis = 1, inplace = True)
print(A)
```

result

```
      cases  population      country  year        type       count
0     745    19987071  Afghanistan  1999  population    19987071
1    2666    20595360  Afghanistan  2000  population    20595360
2   37737   172006362       Brazil  1999  population   172006362
3   80488   174504898       Brazil  2000  population   174504898
4  212258  1272915272        China  1999  population  1272915272
5  213766  1280428583        China  2000  population  1280428583

None
```

Is there something obvious that is escaping me?

Comment: use either A.drop(dropcols, axis = 1, inplace = True) or A = A.drop(dropcols, axis = 1)

Comment: replaced "A = A.drop(....inplace=True)" with just "A.drop(.... inplace=True)", and now it is fine; can someone explain that?

Comment: Using 'inplace' means a 'None' object is returned. So, assigning it to A and printing it yields a 'None' object printed as was the case with your code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>These solutions were mentioned in the comments. I'm just fleshing them out in this post.</sub>

---

When using `drop`, be wary of the two options you have.

One of them is to drop `inplace`. When this is done, the dataframe is operated upon and *changes are made to the original*. This means that this is sufficient.

```
A.drop(dropcols, axis=1, inplace=1)

A
    cases  population      country  year
0     745    19987071  Afghanistan  1999
1    2666    20595360  Afghanistan  2000
2   37737   172006362       Brazil  1999
3   80488   174504898       Brazil  2000
4  212258  1272915272        China  1999
5  213766  1280428583        China  2000
```

As the [`df.drop` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) specifies:

> `inplace` : `bool`, default `False`
>
> If `True`, do operation inplace and return None.

Note that when `drop` is called inplace, it returns `None` (that is the default value of any function that does not return a value), and `A` will have already been updated.

The other option is to drop, but return a copy. This means that the original is not modified. So, you can now do:

```
B = A.drop(dropcols, axis=1)

B    
    cases  population      country  year
0     745    19987071  Afghanistan  1999
1    2666    20595360  Afghanistan  2000
2   37737   172006362       Brazil  1999
3   80488   174504898       Brazil  2000
4  212258  1272915272        China  1999
5  213766  1280428583        China  2000

A
    cases  population      country  year        type       count
0     745    19987071  Afghanistan  1999  population    19987071
1    2666    20595360  Afghanistan  2000  population    20595360
2   37737   172006362       Brazil  1999  population   172006362
3   80488   174504898       Brazil  2000  population   174504898
4  212258  1272915272        China  1999  population  1272915272
5  213766  1280428583        China  2000  population  1280428583
```

Where `B` and `A` exist separately.

Note that you are not saving any memory working with `inplace` - both methods create a copy. However, in the former case, a copy is made behind the scene and the changes are added back into the original object.