# Python DataFrame: Remove timestamp from Timedelta Calculated Field

Tags: python, timestamp, extract, timedelta

UPDATE: See the code below that produced the column I have in my screen shot

```
df_EVENT5_5['age'] = dt.datetime.now().date() - df_EVENT5_5['dt_old']
df_EVENT5_5['age_no_days'] = df_EVENT5_5['age'].dt.total_seconds()/ (24 * 60 * 60)
```

I have a calculated column that's the subtraction of two datetime columns.  The end result looks like below:

[image]

I want to completely remove the timestamp from the field.  How can I do that?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I tried

```
remove_timestamp_col = ['COL_1', 'COL_2']

    for i in remove_timestamp_col:
        df_EVENT5_13[i] = df_EVENT5_13[i].age.days()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that:

string = "9716 days 00:00:00.000000000"

print(string.split(' ', 1))  # split string into words and space is the separator

print(string.split(' ', 1)[0])  # [0] means print first field from dictionary, if you change it to 1 your result will be days 00:00:00.000000000

result = string.split(' ', 1)[0]  # comment or remove print lines if you don't want them

Output:

['9716', 'days 00:00:00.000000000']

9716

Comment: what if I don't want to print ?  still want to keep it as a dataframe

Comment: Can you show the code for the current output? What is the code like to get that list?

Comment: Please see my updated question above that shows the code you are asking for ... thx

Comment: del df['column_name']
or
df = df.drop('column_name', 1)

Maybe that link will help more:
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-using-python-del?rq=1)