# python del vs pandas drop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I know it might be old debate, but out of `pandas.drop` and `python del` function which is better in terms of performance over large dataset?

I am learning machine learning using `python 3` and not sure which one to use. My data is in `pandas` data frame format. But `python del` function is in `built-in function` for python.

Comment: I will suggest to use drop, since it easily can achieve drop multiple column in one time. df.drop(['A','B'])

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-using-python-del

Comment: @Wen achieving multiple column drop wasn't my concern but for larger dataset, if only one column I need to delete,will drop performs better than del or vice versa?

Comment: @Greg this is what I was searching.Thanks a lot..I guess deleting will free some memory from data frame while dropping will just return dataframe while hiding the dropped column, Is it right or am I missing something?

Comment: @sagarjain you can make the `.drop` method work in-place by passing `df.drop(<whatever>, inplace=True)`. I don't think there would be a performance difference. Can't you run a test if you are curios?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried over some datasets in kaggle but found not much  difference.So I was asking.Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 21):

Summarizing a few points about functionality:

- `drop` operates on both columns and rows; `del` operates on column only.
- `drop` can operate on multiple items at a time; `del` operates only on one at a time.
- `drop` can operate in-place or return a copy; `del` is an in-place operation only.

The documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html has more details on `drop`'s features.

Answer (score 12):

Using randomly generated data of about 1.6 GB, it appears that `df.drop` is faster than `del`, especially over multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000,10000))
t_1 = time.time()
df.drop(labels=[2,4,1000], inplace=True)
t_2 = time.time()
print(t_2 - t_1)
```

0.9118959903717041

Compared to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20000,10000))
t_3 = time.time()
del df[2]
del df[4]
del df[1000]
t_4 = time.time()
print(t_4 - t_3)
```

4.052732944488525

@Inder's comparison is not quite the same since it doesn't use `inplace=True`.

Answer (score 7):

tested it on a 10Mb data of stocks, got the following results:

for drop with the following code

```
t=time.time()
d.drop(labels="2")
print(time.time()-t)
```

0.003617525100708008

for del with the following code on the same column:

```
t=time.time()
del d[2]
print(time.time()-t)
```

time i got was:

0.0045168399810791016

reruns on different datasets and columns didn't make any significant difference

Answer (score 1):

In drop method using "inplace=False" you have option to create Subset DF and keep un-touch the original DF, But in del I believe this option is not available.