# pandas: difference between df.pop('x') and df.drop('x', axis=1,inplace=True) and del df['x']?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Do they have the same exact effect (other than the fact that only one returns the popped column)? If so, is there ever a reason to use `df.drop('x', axis=1,inplace=True)` or `del df['x']`over the more concise `df.pop('x')`?

Comment: did you test time for very big table ?

Comment: @furas I did not; should I take that to mean that there is no difference in the effects?

Comment: `pop()` returns column and it is difference which may need more time. And more memory.

Comment: Also touched upon in a few of the answers and comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python del vs pandas drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426089/python-del-vs-pandas-drop)