# Unable to drop column, object has no attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with column titles: name, mfr, type, calories, protein, fat, sodium, fiber, carbo, sugars, vitamins, rating. When I try to drop the sodium column, I don't understand why I'm getting a NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop' error

I've tried

```
df.drop(['sodium'],axis=1) 

df = df.drop(['sodium'],axis=1)

df = df.drop (['sodium'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: after `df = df.drop (['sodium'], 1, inplace=True)` your `df` is `None`. Try to read your csv like this: `df = pd.read_csv(filename).drop(['sodium'],axis=1)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
df = df.drop (['sodium'], 1, inplace=True)
```

This returns `None` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop)) due to the `inplace` flag, and so you no longer have a reference to your dataframe. `df` is now `None` and `None` has no `drop` attribute.

My expectation is that you have done this (or something like it, perhaps dropping another column?) at some prior point in your code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar question, you should have a look at,

[Delete column from pandas DataFrame using del df.column_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-using-del-df-column-name)

According to the answer,

```
`df = df.drop (['sodium'], 1, inplace=True)`
```

should rather be

```
df.drop (['sodium'], 1, inplace=True)
```

Although the first code,

```
df = df.drop(['sodium'],axis=1)
```

should work fine, if there is an error, try

```
print(df.columns)
```

to make sure that the columns are actually read from the csv file

Answer (score 0):

use pd.read_csv(r'File_Path_with_name') and this will be sorted out as there is some issue with reading csv file.