# pandas:drop multiple columns which name in a list and assigned to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns:

```
df
pymnt_plan ... settlement_term days
```

Now  I know which columns I Want to delete/drop, based on the following list:

```
    mylist = ['pymnt_plan',
     'recoveries',
     'collection_recovery_fee',
     'policy_code',
     'num_tl_120dpd_2m',
     'hardship_flag',
     'debt_settlement_flag_date',
     'settlement_status',
     'settlement_date',
     'settlement_amount',
     'settlement_percentage',
     'settlement_term']
```

How to drop multiple columns which their names in a list and assigned to a new dataframe? In this case:

```
df2
days
```

Comment: First of all, never use variable names with 'list'.  l1 = ['col1','col1'...],  `df = df.drop(l1, axis=1)` should work.

Comment: It is dangerous to name a variable `list` with a lower-case `l` because you may have issues when you try to use the `list()` function later in your code.

Comment: @BenG-TWthanks for your advice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete column from pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: the solution you can also find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
new_df = df[list]
df = df.drop(columns=list)
```

Comment: While this should work, Pandas 0.20.3 gives: TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas 0.20.3 using 'df = df.drop(columns=list)' I get:

```
    TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

So you can use this instead:

```
    df = df.drop(axis=1, labels=list)
```