# What is the best way to remove columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am raising this question for my self learning. As far as I know, followings are the different methods to remove columns in pandas dataframe.

Option - 1:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10],'c':[11,12,13,14,15]})
del df['a']
```

Option - 2:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10],'c':[11,12,13,14,15]})
df=df.drop('a',1)
```

Option - 3:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10],'c':[11,12,13,14,15]})
df=df[['b','c']]
```

1. What is the best approach among these?
2. Any other approaches to achieve the same?

Comment: Option-2 is the most common. It's pandas way to delete columns from dataframe.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Follow the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe):

> DataFrame is a **2-dimensional labeled data structure** with columns of potentially different types.

And [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop):

> **Drop specified labels** from rows or columns.

So, I think we should stick with `df.drop`. Why? I think the pros are:

1. It gives us more control of the remove action:

   ```
   # This will return a NEW DataFrame object, leave the original `df` untouched.
   df.drop('a', axis=1)  
   # This will modify the `df` inplace. **And return a `None`**.
   df.drop('a', axis=1, inplace=True)
   ```
2. It can handle more complicated cases with it's args. E.g. with `level`, we can handle MultiIndex deletion. And with `errors`, we can prevent some bugs.
3. It's a more unified and object oriented way.

---

And just like @jezrael noted in his answer:

Option 1: Using key word `del` is a limited way.

Option 3: And `df=df[['b','c']]` isn't even a deletion in essence. It first [select data by indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) with `[]` syntax, then unbind the name `df` with the original DataFrame and bind it with the new one (i.e. `df[['b','c']]`).

Answer (score 15):

The recommended way to delete a column or row in pandas dataframes is using drop.

To delete a column,

```
df.drop('column_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

To delete a row,

```
df.drop('row_index', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

You can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-using-del-df-column-name) to see a detailed conversation about column delete approaches.

Answer (score 4):

From a speed perspective, option 1 seems to be the best. Obviously, based on the other answers, that doesn't mean it's actually the best option.

```
In [52]: import timeit

In [53]: s1 = """
    ...: import pandas as pd
    ...: df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10],'c':[11,12,13,14,15]})
    ...: del df['a']
    ...: """

In [54]: s2 = """
    ...: import pandas as pd
    ...: df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10],'c':[11,12,13,14,15]})
    ...: df=df.drop('a',1)
    ...: """

In [55]: s3 = """
    ...: import pandas as pd
    ...: df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,10],'c':[11,12,13,14,15]})
    ...: df=df[['b','c']]
    ...: """

In [56]: timeit.timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000)
Out[56]: 53.37321400642395

In [57]: timeit.timeit(stmt=s2, number=100000)
Out[57]: 79.68139410018921

In [58]: timeit.timeit(stmt=s3, number=100000)
Out[58]: 76.25269913673401
```

Comment: Since you are using IPython, you can just use `%timeit` [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) built in IPython: `%timeit -n 100000 df=df.drop('a',1)`.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best is use 2. and 3. option, because first has limits - you can remove only one column and [cannot use dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37000877) - `del df.a`.

3.solution is not deleting, but selecting and [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46314092) create nice answer for multiple possible solutions with same idea.