# Drop the columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

col_exclusions = ['numerator','Numerator' 'Denominator', "denominator"]

dataframe

```
id prim_numerator sec_Numerator tern_Numerator tern_Denominator final_denominator Result

1       12                23           45          54                      56         Fail
```

Final output is id and Result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete column from pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167612/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-columns-in-pandas

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar This is not my question

Comment: Im having column names combined with word numerator etc so if numerator comes in any place means i have to remove that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using regex

```
import re

pat = re.compile('|'.join(col_exclusions),flags=re.IGNORECASE)

final_cols = [c for c in df.columns if not re.search(pat,c)]

#out:

['id', 'Result']
```

---

```
print(df[final_cols])

   id Result
0   1   Fail
```

if you want to drop

```
df = df.drop([c for c in df.columns if re.search(pat,c)],axis=1)
```

or the pure pandas approach thanks to @Anky_91

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(col_exclusions),case=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be explicit and use `del` for columns that contain the suffixes in your input list:

```
for column in df.columns:
    if any([column.endswith(suffix) for suffix in col_exclusions]):
        del df[column]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following approach where the column names are splitted then matched with `col_exclusions`

```
df.drop(columns=[i for i in df.columns if i.split("_")[-1] in col_exclusions], inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: classic case of FGITW, smh :-(