# Calculate mean for all the columns every 12 hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe and i want to calculate every 12 hours mean for all the columns.
dataframe has more than 200k rows.

```
          DateTime Speed   TRQ         ...    PtoP3  RMS3   Crest3
0       2016-07-01 00:00   994  35.4   ...       NA    NA       NA
1       2016-07-01 00:01   995  34.6   ...       NA    NA       NA
2       2016-07-01 00:02   995    34   ...       NA    NA       NA
```

i wrote this

```
Present_data.to_datetime(Present_data['DateTime'])
Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H', key='DateTime')).mean()
print(Total_12hravg_all)
```

and got this error

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: First try `Present_data['DateTime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(Present_data['DateTime'])`

Comment: @Alexhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/2411802/alexanderander Still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If `Datetime` is column**:

Your solution shoud be working nice:

```
Present_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Present_data['DateTime'])
Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H', key='DateTime')).mean()
```

Alternative solution is use `resample` with parameter `on`:

```
Present_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Present_data['DateTime'])
Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.resample('12H', on='DateTime').mean()
```

Or create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
Present_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Present_data['DateTime'])
Present_data = Present_data.set_index('DateTime')
Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H')).mean()
#resample
#Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.resample('12H').mean()
```

**If `Datetime` is index**:

```
Present_data.index = pd.to_datetime(Present_data.index)

Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H')).mean()
#resample
#Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.resample('12H').mean()
```

Final solution:

```
Present_data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Present_data['DateTime'])
Present_data = Present_data.set_index('DateTime')

#convert non numeri values to NaNs
Present_data = Present_data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H')).mean()
#resample
#Total_12hravg_all = Present_data.resample('12H').mean()
```

Comment: i have a dataframe Total_12hravg_all in which there are two columns PtoP3 and RMS3 and i need to replace RMS3 Values to nan if PtoP3 contains Nan for the same row. how can i do that?

Comment: @prashantsharma - Use `Present_data.loc[Present_data['PtoP3'].isnull(), 'RMS3'] = np.nan`

Comment: how can i delete whole dataframe and some variable ?? will del work ??

Comment: @prashantsharma - better is `drop` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18145399

Comment: i want to change all of the columns of my dataframe to -1 wherever nan is present. just removing RMS3 from the above statement will work?

Comment: and i aso want to change my whole column names to be small letter

Comment: @prashantsharma - Please try create new question.