# Not able to drop multiple columns from a .csv file in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm reading a csv file that has 7 columns

```
df = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=['Wheel','Date','1ex','2ex','3ex','4ex','5ex'])
```

The problem is that the model I want to train with it, is complaining about the first 2 columns being Strings, so I want to drop them.
I first tried not to read the from the beginning with :

```
df = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=['1ex','2ex','3ex','4ex','5ex'])
```

but it only shifted the values of two columns..so I decided to drop them. 
The problem is that I'm only able to drop the first column `'Date'` with

```
train_df.drop(columns=['Date'], inplace=True)
```

, `train_df` is a portion of `df` uses for testing. How do I go to also drop `'Wheel'` column?
I tried

```
train_df.drop(labels=[["Date","Wheel"]], inplace=True)
```

but i get `KeyError: "[('Date', 'Wheel')] not found in axis"`
so I tried

```
train_df.drop(columns=[["Date","Wheel"]], index=1, inplace=True)
```

but I still get the same error.
I'm so new to Python I'm out of resources to solve this.
As always many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete column from pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: this is well discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @PV8 well..sorry, I'm very new to it, I actually found that second post you suggested, but I wasn't sure about deleting the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
train_df.drop(columns=["Date","Wheel"], index=1, inplace=True)
```

See the examples in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: Absolutely working thanks! So it was the double `[ ]` that created the problem. I actually did tried it before, but without the `index=1`, the guide I found misled me using the double `[ ]`. Thanks for the link and for not down voting me ;)

Comment: @Anakin87 I am new to Python, so maybe that's why I am confused; but my question is regarding the `train_df`, not the process of dropping columns. How does the compiler knows this variable is trying to drop columns from the `df`, while the `train_df`was not assigned to `df` before?

Comment: In the question, the author explains that `train_df` is a portion of `df`, but he doesn't specify how this portion is defined: a line of code is missing.