# Python pandas: Why doesnt `del df.loc[:,column_name]` work? (Even though `del df[column_name]` does?

Tags: python, pandas

The most common way to delete columns from a dataframe seems to be `del df["column_name"]`

However, `del df.loc[:,column_name]` does not work even though `df["column_name"]` and `df.loc[:,common_name]` do essentially the same thing.

I'm actually wondering because I'm hoping there's an equally easy method of deleting rows. Rows can't be accessed with the direct `df[]` syntax, so I'd have to use `del df.loc[]`, which as I've described doesn't work even if I'm dealing with a column

Why doesnt `del df.loc[:,column_name]` work, even though `del df[column_name]` does?

Comment: I assumed the most appropirate way to remove columns was to use `.drop` whilst specifying the axis. same for rows, `df.drop([0,4,5],0)`

Comment: @Datanovice Indeed, but that's assuming you know the index which can be hard to get sometimes. I guess you also need to know column names for the `del` usage, but in my experience row indices are harder to figure out, and it's usually rows I'm searching through in one way or another

Comment: Then I think you have a specific usecase, why don't you add some data to show your problem and i'll have a crack at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As for why `del df.loc[:, column]` does not work, I assume because it's not baked into the API, the developers made `.drop` for a reason!

[You can read here more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe), where even Wes the main author of Pandas recommend's `del` but see the other answers and comments for a wider discussion regarding best practice.

## You can use [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

from the documenation.

> Drop specified labels from rows or columns.
>
> Remove rows or columns by specifying label names and corresponding
> axis, or by specifying directly index or column names. When using a
> multi-index, labels on different levels can be removed by specifying
> the level.

## Drop on a named index, specifying the axis `0` for index. `1` is for columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],

               'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],

               'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},

              index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])


print(df)

        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8


print(df.drop(['falcon','dog'],0))
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8
```

## Drop based on an integer based index.

```
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))

df = pd.get_dummies(s)

print(df)

   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0

print(df.drop([0,2],0))

    a   b   c
1   0   1   0
3   1   0   0
```

## Drop a column.

```
print(df.drop(['a'],1))

  b  c
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  0  0
```