# After I drop columns, I run my linear regression and the columns are there

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I am very new, like going through school new. I am trying to do multiple linear regression and the columns I am trying to stop are still in the linear regression.

```
df= df.drop('Income','Yearly_equip_failure','Email','Techie','Population',
    'Port_modem','PaperlessBilling')
```

I run the sm.OLS code

```
model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)
```

```
print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)
```

These are some of the few columns

```
Outage_sec_perweek                         0.0003      0.000      0.809      0.419      -0.000       0.001
Email                                   -6.71e-05      0.000     -0.189      0.850      -0.001       0.001
Contacts
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Your format is incorrect.  If you're dropping multiple rows, you have to specify them in a sequence -- usually a list.

```
df= df.drop( [ 'Income', 'Yearly_equip_failure', 'Email',
               'Techie', 'Population',
               'Port_modem','PaperlessBilling' 
             ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Prune the syntax used is incorrect:

Adding to that I suggest you to please refer to [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for more information.

Please remember that it is much more prudent to explicitly define what features you aim to drop i.e.

```
df = df.drop([A,B,C])
```

This may create an issue as it doesn't specify what are you trying to drop.
It is a better practice to use

```
df = df.drop(columns = [A,B,C])
```

as it improves readability of your code.

Note: Always remember to toggle **inplace** flag when working with df.drop

Comment: Thank you very much. The second way worked. I should have known this but I guess I have been staring at this too long.