# How to transform GET response to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I have read several responses on here from several years ago that suggests something like this would bring me from an API response to a pandas dataframe:

```
r = requests.request("GET", get_url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(r.text)

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json())
```

However, the result of this is:

[image: Dataframe Preview]

I end up with two columns, one "count" and one "leases" that contains the actual output per unique identifier. It is what I see in that leases column that I would like converted into a dataframe. Is there a simple way to do this? I think I need to remove the most outward nest with the "count" portion of the response but I am not sure how to achieve this elegantly.

JSON text response from the API (clipped):

```
{"count":298,"leases":[{"itemId":0,"leaseInst":328,"leas [...]
```

I am avoiding the older posts that suggest normalize_json because it appears to be deprecated, sadly.

Comment: This link talks about deleting unwanted columns in a df, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe?rq=1

Comment: I think you would just want to make a DF out of the `leases` so use `df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json()["leases"])`.

Comment: json_normalize is deprecated? I don't think so

Comment: @yudhiesh That did it, thank you!