# How to create a dataframe from csv file without the index column (using python pandas)?

Tags: pandas

My script uses `pd.read_csv('example.csv')` to create data frames in python using pandas.  The original CSV files being read only have two columns, but the data frame created by this `read_csv` method is prepended with sort of an index-like column.

CSV before reading it:

```
text     100
text     200
text     300
text     400
```

but after reading it:

```
         text     100
0        text     200
1        text     300
3        text     400
```

For the life of me, I can't get rid of that first column.  Everything I try instead deletes the **second** column.  I've tried a number of suggestions found online including:

`df = df.iloc[: , 1:]` (from [here](https://thispointer.com/pandas-delete-first-column-of-dataframe-in-python/))

`df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe))

`df = df.drop("", 1)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

For each of those, I either get an error or it removes the *second* column, leaving me with:

```
         100
0        200
1        300
3        400
```

UPDATES:

I have also tried: `df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', index_col=False)` and I still get the index column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `df.to_csv()` on your constructed DataFrame, pass index=False, like:

```
df.to_csv('target_file.csv', index=False)
```

See also the [DataFrame.to_csv() doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Thanks @sarah-messer, That would be perfect if I were trying to create a csv from a dataframe. I'm trying to create a dataframe from a csv (using read_csv currently).  I've tried a few things to include to_csv with no luck.

Comment: Ah, by adding the 'index=False' to the point where I create an output file solved it!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following `pd.read_csv('example.csv',index_col=False)`

Comment: Thanks @AJ31. I have also tried that and it still produces an index column