# delete all columns name's "NaN" in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Please how to delete all columns name's "NaN" in Pandas DataFrame

[image: Here image of my df]

Comment: Have you checked how to [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18145399/2246849)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried so far, and explain what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
 df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notna()]
```

Comment: Does not work 
KeyError: "['NaN'] not found in axis"

Comment: Now I understand , I edited the answer