# How to delete a specific column from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python. I would like to ask regarding how can you delete a specific columns in a pandas dataframe. This is my dataframe:

Pandas Dataframe:

[image: Pandas Dataframe]

I would like to delete the column "tahun" and "jenis" as its have the same value for every month. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop(columns=['tahun','jenis'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you specify what does inplace do?

Comment: 'inplace' updates the df but will not have the dropped columns. Alternate of it is to assign it to another df.  Try out with and without 'inplace' to see the difference