# change column name from JSON file data

Tags: python, pandas

I added a `datetime` to my data and I want to get rid of the old one, so it looks cleaner! Is it possible to change the title from `data.dataset` to something else?

I tried df.rename(columns={"data.datasets":"mydata"}) but unfortunately no changes :(

```py
import datetime

#convert the column to datetime:
df["data.date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["data.date"])
df["date"] = df["data.date"].apply(lambda x : x.date())

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

# First for the day:
df = df.resample('d').first()

# Print only 5/05 - 6/05
print(df.loc[df.index.to_series().between('2022-05-05', '2022-06-05')])
```

This is what the data currently looks like:

```
   data.date  data.datasets        Time       date                                                     
2022-05-05 2022-05-05 04:19:35         3.0500  2022-05-05
2022-05-06 2022-05-06 00:10:24         2.3500  2022-05-06
2022-05-07 2022-05-07 00:10:47         4.0900  2022-05-07
2022-05-08 2022-05-08 00:08:13         3.8790  2022-05-08
2022-05-09 2022-05-09 00:13:24         3.5780  2022-05-09
2022-05-10 2022-05-10 00:08:49         3.7500  2022-05-10
2022-05-11 2022-05-11 00:09:33         4.3900  2022-05-11
2022-05-12 2022-05-12 00:08:24         3.6900  2022-05-12
2022-05-13 2022-05-13 00:08:45         3.4300  2022-05-13
2022-05-14 2022-05-14 00:08:55         3.9500  2022-05-14
```

Comment: So basically do you just want to change the column names of the data frame?

Comment: @AfsanaKhan since i already added the time with datetime i'd prefer to remove the data.date on the left (repeats 2x i dont like the look of it)

Comment: Not important, but it looks like your sample output is missing a column header.

Comment: @AfsanaKhan, that is not quite right. The forum is exactly for this kind of question. OP could have search SO first, naturally, but the question is still **on-topic** here, even if it is a simple one.

Comment: @accdias These are duplicate questions. So according to the rules, the first task is to look for similar questions and only ask if the previous questions don't answer the question.

Comment: @AfsanaKhan, indeed. So, a better approach, would be indicating it is a duplicate and pointing OP to the right answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: my bad new to overflow and coding i sometimes don't know exactly what to search for, thought it'd be easier to just ask haha

Comment: @accdias it does but the renaming column code doesnt work :( not sure how to get aroudn that (df.rename(columns={"data.datasets":"mydata"})

Comment: @AfsanaKhan i edited my question for clarification!

Comment: @catlean, take a look at [_Renaming column names in Pandas_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas). Use the search form above, in the header.

Comment: @AfsanaKhan i tried that code and it also didn't work. not sure if it's cause of my file, but the data.dataset and date aren't lined up together - it's above the data while the date is in line with the dates (if this explanation makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the column(s) by providing a dictionary {}:

```
df.rename(columns={"data.datasets":"mydata"})
```

Removing a column:

```
df.drop(columns="data.date", inplace=True)
```

Comment: hi!! the removal of a column code worked but renaming didn't :( any idea why?

Comment: use df.columns to get the exact column names, sometimes there can be a hard to spot typo or space.

also use df.rename(columns={"data.datasets":"something"}, inplace="True") to edit inplace

Comment: i did inplace=true and it worked!! :3 thanks for the help