# Changing a column type in a very large pandas dataframe is too slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have a very large dataframe, around 80GB. I want to change the type of some of its columns from object to category. Trying to do it this way:

```
df[col_name] = df[col_name].astype('category')
```

Takes around 1 minute per column, which is a lot. My first question would be why does it take that long?
Just running:

```
df[col_name].astype('category')
```

takes just around 1 second.
I tried something like:

```
temp = df[col_name].astype('category')
df.drop(columns=[col_name])
df[col_name] = temp
```

In this case it turns out that dropping the column is also very slow.
Now, I also tried replacing drop by del, that is

```
temp = df[col_name].astype('category')
del df[col_name]
df[col_name] = temp
```

Surprisingly (for me) this was very fast. So My second question is why is del so much faster than drop in this case? What is the most "correct" way of doing this conversion, and what is the most efficient (hopefully they are the same)?
Thanks

Comment: `del` would map this operation to df.__delitem__('column name'), which is an internal method of DataFrame. `df.pop(col_name)` is also faster than `drop`. `del` is not recommended to delete columnaccording to the answer to this question [Delete a column from a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-a-column-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: hi, I know this is an old thread but I am facing the same issue. What did you end up doing if you recall?

Comment: 1 second is pretty fast for a large dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
df['col_name'].values.astype('category')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as df[col_name].astype('category') ?
The conversion itself is fast. Reassigning the column in the dataframe seems to be the slow operation.

Comment: Hmmm I thought the problem was the slow part.

Comment: Yes, but the slow part is not df[col_name].astype('category') but reassigning the column back to the dataframe