# Create function to to detect dictionary types and extract the keys and values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, key-value

I have been given a dataframe that includes dictionaries and nested dictionaries.

See here the examples and the different types of dictionaries one will find: type 1 (test_dict_1), type 2 (test_dict_2):

```
test_dict_1={'results': [{'key': 'q1',
   'value': ['1'],
   'end_time': '2021-01-21',
   'start_time': '2021-01-21',
   'result_type': 'multipleChoice'},
  {'key': 'q2',
   'value': ['False'],
   'end_time': '2021-01-21',
   'start_time': '2021-01-21',
   'result_type': 'multipleChoice'},
  {'key': 'q3',
   'value': ['3'],
   'end_time': '2021-01-21',
   'start_time': '2021-01-21',
   'result_type': 'multipleChoice'},
  {'key': 'q4',
   'value': ['3'],
   'end_time': '2021-01-21',
   'start_time': '2021-01-21',
   'result_type': 'multipleChoice'}]}
  


test_dict_2={'results': [{'key': 'survey_x',
   'value': [[{'key': 'q1',
      'value': 2,
      'endTime': '2021-01-21',
      'skipped': False,
      'startTime': '2021-01-21',
      'resultType': 'multipleChoice'},
     {'key': 'q2',
      'value': 0,
      'endTime': '2021-01-21',
      'skipped': False,
      'startTime': '2021-01-21',
      'resultType': 'multipleChoice'},
     {'key': 'q3',
      'value': 2,
      'endTime':'2021-01-21',
      'skipped': False,
      'startTime': '2021-01-21',
      'resultType': 'multipleChoice'},
     {'key': 'q4',
      'value': 0,
      'endTime': '2021-01-21',
      'skipped': False,
      'startTime':'2021-01-21',
      'resultType': 'multipleChoice'}]],
   'skipped': False,
   'end_time': '2021-01-21',
   'start_time': '2021-01-21',
   'result_type': 'grouped'}]}
```

My goal is to create a function that detects the type of dictionary, and for each type, create a dataframe using the `key` and `values`.

Note, however, that in the type 2, one has to go deeper, and the dataframe that I would want looks like this

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(test_dict_2['results'][0]['value'][0])

df_2 = df_2[['key', 'value']]

[Out]:
  key  value
0  q1      2
1  q2      0
2  q3      2
3  q4      0
```

The following function is able to extract the key and values, but doesn't detect the dictionary type, so it doesn't retrieve the desired for type 2 dictionaries (unless one reads them as referred in the previous operation).

```
def extract_keys_values(df):
    # Create a list of dictionaries
    list_of_dicts = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # Create a dictionary for each row
        dict_ = {}
        for key, value in row.items():
            # If the value is a list, extract the first element
            if isinstance(value, list):
                value = value[0]
            # If the value is a dictionary, extract the value
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                value = value['value']
            # Add key and value to dictionary
            dict_[key] = value
        # Add dictionary to list
        list_of_dicts.append(dict_)
    # Create dataframe from list of dictionaries
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
    return df
```

My desired goal is a function that detects the type of dictionary, and adjust the way that the dataframe is created:

• If type 1, do something like the following

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(test_dict_1['results'])
```

• If type 2, do something like the following

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(test_dict_2['results'][0]['value'][0])
```

Comment: Do you have any control over the format the data comes in? Are these the only two structures of dictionaries that are possible?

Comment: I have no control over the format, unfortunately. These are the only two types of dictionaries found in the column.

Comment: @Gonçalo Peres, this is not the desired format that I want. 

I would like the function to add a column to the original dataframe with only the keys and values from the dictionaries in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far not the prettiest solution, but this works for my messy dataframe:

```
def recursive_items(dictionary):
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if type(value) is dict:
        yield from recursive_items(value)
    else:
        yield (key, value)

def extract_keys_values(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
    #    print(i)
        global_dict={}
        for key_, value_ in recursive_items(df.loc[i, 0]):
            for element in value_:
                keys_ = dict((k, element[k]) for k in ['key'] if k in element)
                texts_ = dict((k, element[k]) for k in ['text'] if k in element)
                values_ = dict((k, element[k]) for k in ['value'] if k in element)

                if 'key' in str(values_):
                    for key, value in values_.items():
                        try:
                            nested_keys_list=list(object['key'] for object in value[0])
                            nested_values_list=list(object['value'] for object in value[0])
                        except:
                            nested_keys_list=list(object['key'] for object in [value][0])
                            nested_values_list=list(object['value'] for object in [value][0])
                        for list_index, word in enumerate(nested_keys_list):
                            if isinstance(nested_values_list[list_index], list):
                                try:
                                    nested_dictionaries={word,nested_values_list[list_index][0]}
                                except:
                                    nested_dictionaries={word,''}
                            else:
                                nested_dictionaries={word,nested_values_list[list_index]}
                                new_data_dictionary=dict.fromkeys(keys_.values(),[nested_dictionaries])

                else:
                    new_data_dictionary=dict.fromkeys(keys_.values(),values_)
                
                if bool(texts_):
                    new_data_dictionary.update(texts_)
                global_dict.update(new_data_dictionary)

        #    print(global_dict)
        df.loc[i,'data_key_value']=[global_dict]

    return df['data_key_value']

df['data_key_value']=extract_keys_values(df)
```